# How to determine video codec of a file with FFmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I often have problems reading AVI files with my TV's DVD player if they are not DivX or Xvid (e.g., DX50 is not readable). I'd like to make a fast script to determine the video codec of these files before burning them to CD-ROM or DVD.

The following prints the "container" of the video stream (mpeg4, mpeg2, etc), but not the codec:

```
ffmpeg -i file.avi
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce. ffmpeg-0.5-5.20091026svn.fc12.x86_64

Answer (score 125):

## [mediainfo](https://github.com/MediaArea/MediaInfo)

```
mediainfo --Inform="Video;%Codec%" video.mkv
```

will in my case return:

```
V_MPEG4/ISO/AVC
```

Answer made possible thanks to [How to find duration of a video file using mediainfo in seconds or other formats?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19091772/188159)

## ffprobe (ffmpeg) easy way

Assuming your video has one video stream only:

```
ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=codec_name -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 video.mkv
```

Will in my case return:

```
h264
```

Answer made possible thanks to [How to get video duration in seconds?](https://superuser.com/a/945604/38668)

## ffprobe (ffmpeg) dirty way

This method is easier to understand but messy.

To get the codec information without playing back the file, use `ffprobe`.

```
$ ffprobe video.mkv
[...]
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'video.mkv':
  Metadata:
    ENCODER         : Lavf56.25.101
  Duration: 00:28:05.15, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 4353 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High 4:4:4 Predictive), yuv444p, 1280x960, SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 1k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      ENCODER         : Lavc56.26.100 libx264
    Stream #0:1: Audio: vorbis, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      ENCODER         : Lavc56.26.100 libvorbis
```

To extract the video codec information - since ffmpeg sends information to stderr - [pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342826/how-to-pipe-stderr-and-not-stdout) and grep it:

```
$ ffprobe video.mkv 2>&1 >/dev/null | grep Stream.*Video
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High 4:4:4 Predictive), yuv444p, 1280x960, SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 1k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
```

To reduce the output even further, introduce sed:

```
$ ffprobe video.mkv 2>&1 >/dev/null |grep Stream.*Video | sed -e 's/.*Video: //' -e 's/[, ].*//'
h264
```

Comment: You can also use -show_streams (and other related options) instead of using the somewhat obscure and unstable sed/grep options. "ffprobe $file -show_streams | grep ^codec_name=" would give the codec output, but in a more forward-compatible method.

Comment: `$ ffprobe video.mkv` rules :)

Comment: If you need to check an MP4 file for Quicktime format, this is the command using ffprobe: `ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries format=format_long_name -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 videofile.mp4` will result in `QuickTime / MOV` if quicktime.

Comment: Standard mp4 files seem also to throw "QuickTime / MOV" as "format_long_name". So I am checking the `codec_name` instead: `ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=codec_name -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 videofile.mp4`

Answer (score 8):

FFmpeg gives the codec too.  Pull the `Stream #0.0: Video` line and you can see the codec.  (Be aware that it could technically have a different stream number, like 0.1.)  The below output uses the MS Video-1.  This is different, like you desire, from the container which is denoted by `Input #0, avi`

E.g.:

```
FFmpeg version 0.5, Copyright (c) 2000-2009 Fabrice Bellard, et al.
  configuration: --prefix=/opt/local --disable-vhook --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libtheora --enable-libdirac --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libfaac --enable-libfaad --enable-libxvid --enable-libx264 --mandir=/opt/local/share/man --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --cc=/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 --arch=x86_64
  libavutil     49.15. 0 / 49.15. 0
  libavcodec    52.20. 0 / 52.20. 0
  libavformat   52.31. 0 / 52.31. 0
  libavdevice   52. 1. 0 / 52. 1. 0
  libavfilter    1. 4. 0 /  1. 4. 0
  libswscale     1. 7. 1 /  1. 7. 1
  libpostproc   51. 2. 0 / 51. 2. 0
  built on Jan  8 2010 15:34:15, gcc: 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646) (dot 1)
Input #0, avi, from 'Movies/fvss_demo.avi':
  Duration: 00:02:00.30, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 719 kb/s
    Stream #0.0: Video: msvideo1, rgb555, 160x120, 10 tbr, 10 tbn, 10 tbc
    Stream #0.1: Audio: pcm_u8, 8000 Hz, mono, s16, 64 kb/s
At least one output file must be specified
manoa:~ stu$
```

Comment: Thanks. This is considerably faster than `mediainfo`.

Answer (score 3):

Try [MediaInfo](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/en) instead.

It lists the codec for each stream and its output is simple enough to parse - there's also an XML output option if you prefer XPath like queries.

Answer (score 1):

ffmpeg has it.  On mac i did it this way :

first download ffmpeg like this:

```
brew install ffmpeg --with-fdk-aac --with-ffplay --with-freetype --with-frei0r --with-libass --with-libvo-aacenc --with-libvorbis --with-libvpx --with-opencore-amr --with-openjpeg --with-opus --with-rtmpdump --with-schroedinger --with-speex --with-theora --with-tools
```

and then run this on the command line:

```
ffmpeg -filter:v idet \
    -frames:v 100 \
    -an \
    -f rawvideo -y /dev/null \
    -i ~/Downloads/yourfile.mp4
```

then check for something like this in the output:

Duration: 00:00:05.48, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 952 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: **h264** (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 750x1334, 619 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)

Answer (score 0):

With the current version of ffmpeg it is enough to run `ffmpeg -i <my-video-file.mp4>` to produce:

```
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    creation_time   : 2023-05-03T15:06:15.000000Z
    encoder         : HandBrake 1.2.2 2019022300
  Duration: 00:28:45.93, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 381 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 243 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2023-05-03T15:06:15.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 129 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2023-05-03T15:06:15.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

So you can see this particular file contains audio encoded in AAC-LC and video in H.264. No encoding is done, so the operation is immediate.

*ffmpeg version 4.2*