# Is there a way to use ffmpeg to determine the encoding of a file before transcoding?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing, video-encoding

I am planning to use ffmpeg to ensure all video files uploaded to my website are encoded as mp4 h264.

Rather than automatically processing every file I would like to minimise the processing overhead by only processing those files that are not already mp4 h264. Is there an easy way to do this either with ffmpeg or with another command line utility?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to recognize video codec of a file with ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2869281/how-to-recognize-video-codec-of-a-file-with-ffmpeg)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If you pass an input file to ffmpeg, without other parameters, it will give you information about the video source:

```
ffmpeg -i myfile.avi
```

Another way would be the `-identify` option of mplayer, which might be slightly easier to parse. There is a wrapper script `midentify` which gives you even better output. See [this example.](http://jorgenmodin.net/index_html/archive/2010/01/04/midentify---a-script-that-gives-you-information-on-a-video-file)

Comment: Great that gives me the info I need. Would like not to have to parse the output though :)

Comment: MediaInfo can do this and has optional XML output. http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/en - grab the command line version.

Comment: ffmpeg package includes command `ffprobe` that supports several output formats such as xml and json. Eases parsing of ffmpeg output

Answer (score 65):

## Use `ffprobe`

#### Example command

```
$ ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=codec_name -of default=nokey=1:noprint_wrappers=1 input.mp4
```

#### Result

```
h264
```

#### Option descriptions

- `-v error` Omit extra information except for fatal errors.
- `-select_streams v:0` Select only the first video stream. Otherwise the `codec_name` for all other streams in the file, such as audio, will be shown as well.
- `-show_entries stream=codec_name` Only output the `codec_name` instead of all stream info.
- `-of default=nokey=1:noprint_wrappers=1` Select the default output format style and omit the key and wrapper info. Otherwise, without these options, it will output:

  ```
    [STREAM]
    codec_name=h264
    [/STREAM]
  ```

#### Also see

- [`ffprobe` documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html)
- [FFmpeg Wiki: FFprobe Tips](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/FFprobeTips)

#### Bash script example

Only re-encode if video is not H.264:

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir h264vids

for f in *.mkv
do
  audioformat=$(ffprobe -loglevel error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=codec_name -of default=nw=1:nk=1 "$f")
  if [ "$audioformat" = "h264" ]; then
    ffmpeg -i "$f" -c:v copy -c:a aac -movflags +faststart h264vids/"${f%.*}.mp4"
  else
    ffmpeg -i "$f" -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -movflags +faststart h264vids/"${f%.*}.mp4"
  fi
done
```

This is a simple script and will ignore additional video streams if you input has more than one.

Answer (score 7):

An alternative is to use `ffprobe` which is included with ffmpeg. The following will give the most terse output I can find from the ffmpeg tools:

```
ffprobe -hide_banner -stats -i myfile.avi
```

Answer (score 2):

As llogan said above, let me simplify it for other new leaners，video265.mp4 is your video file:

```
ffprobe -v error -show_entries stream=codec_name video265.mp4
```

Result:

```
[STREAM]
codec_name=hevc
[/STREAM]
```