# FFmpeg file conversion formats and file extensions

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, video-conversion, audio-converter

I hope someone knows a link to point me to here.

I'm converting different video and audio formats using ffmpeg. I want to only let files with file extensions be converted that are supported by ffmpeg. The supported formats are found here: http://ffmpeg.org/general.html#SEC4

My question: is there a **list of file extensions** somewhere? I don't want to research for every format which file extensions might be used for that. Or is there a pain-free format-recognition library or class for C#/.NET available, that can scan for a audio/video format?

Comment: Multimedia files are often *container* files which can contain many different possible *codecs*. Thus you'd sometimes have to look inside the file to see what codecs are being used, to be sure - just looking at the file extension wouldn't necessarily be enough.

Comment: Ah okay. So is there a (hopefully painless) way to recognize the codec inside the container and to determine if it can be used by ffmpeg in C#/.NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call ffmpeg with just the input file and no other parameters, it will give you information on the contained streams, if it can read them.

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi
```

See this answer about [identifying files before encoding.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618363/is-there-a-way-to-use-ffmpeg-to-determine-the-encoding-of-a-file-before-transcodi/5619907#5619907)

Comment: Thanks ... sad that there's no programmatic way - but this will work.

Comment: Or, look at ffprobe.  You still need to shell to execute it, but you can get it to dump a JSON output as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7708373/get-ffmpeg-information-in-friendly-way

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just programmatically execute

```
ffmpeg -i filename -dframes 0 -vn -aframes 0 dummy.avi
```

and read the output and see if it says "Unsupported codec" or something like that at the end?

That encodes zero audio frames and nothing else into a dummy file. Actually you might need to tweak the options a little, because I'm not sure whether that will check if the video codec is supported.