# Get ffmpeg information in friendly way

Tags: json, parsing, ffmpeg

Every time I try to get some information about my video files with ffmpeg, it pukes a lot of useless information mixed with good things.

I'm using `ffmpeg -i name_of_the_video.mpg`.

There are any possibilities to get that in a friendly way? I mean JSON would be great (and even ugly XML is fine).

By now, I made my application parse the data with regex but there are lots of nasty corners that appear on some specific video files. I fixed all that I encountered, but there may be more.

I wanted something like:

```
{
  "Stream 0": {
     "type": "Video",
     "codec": "h264",
     "resolution": "720x480"
  },
  "Stream 1": {
     "type": "Audio",
     "bitrate": "128 kbps",
     "channels": 2
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at [ffprobe](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ffprobe/)? It seems to provide a JSON readable output.

Comment: I've lookead at it already but couldn't find the JSON output format

Answer (score 324, accepted):

A bit late, but perhaps still relevant to someone..

`ffprobe` is indeed an excellent way to go. Note, though, that you need to tell `ffprobe` what information you want it to display (with the `-show_format`, `-show_packets` and `-show_streams` options) or it'll just give you blank output (like you mention in one of your comments).

For example, `ffprobe -v quiet -print_format json -show_format -show_streams somefile.asf` would yield something like the following:

```
{
  "streams": [{
    "index": 0,
    "codec_name": "wmv3",
    "codec_long_name": "Windows Media Video 9",
    "codec_type": "video",
    "codec_time_base": "1/1000",
    "codec_tag_string": "WMV3",
    "codec_tag": "0x33564d57",
    "width": 320,
    "height": 240,
    "has_b_frames": 0,
    "pix_fmt": "yuv420p",
    "level": -99,
    "r_frame_rate": "30000/1001",
    "avg_frame_rate": "0/0",
    "time_base": "1/1000",
    "start_time": "0.000",
    "duration": "300.066",
    "tags": {
        "language": "eng"
    }
  }],
  "format": {
    "filename": "somefile.asf",
    "nb_streams": 1,
    "format_name": "asf",
    "format_long_name": "ASF format",
    "start_time": "0.000",
    "duration": "300.066",
    "tags": {
        "WMFSDKVersion": "10.00.00.3646",
        "WMFSDKNeeded": "0.0.0.0000",
        "IsVBR": "0"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If anyone ever need, I've written a PHP solution based on that answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11805207/how-to-parse-ffmpeg-info-in-php#11807265

Comment: Sorry for digging this out, but is there any chance to speed this up? It takes 5-6 seconds to show the output

Comment: That final sentence is exactly what I needed. Thanks :)

Comment: my app close with out displaying any message, when I use ffprob command! why??? but ffmpeg works fine

Comment: people... asking a question in a comment to an answer from 4 years ago has about zero chance of getting answered...

Comment: Other formats can also be used - XML etc: https://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe-all.html#toc-Writers

Comment: You can also use ```-of json``` instead of ```-print_format json```. The former is compatible with ```avprobe``` while the latter not.

Comment: I find myself coming back to this somewhat often. Great answer!

Comment: This is the correct answer! I was wondering why `ffmpeg` cannot output the same results, considering that `ffprobe` is built using the same libraries...

Comment: @patrick I would more blame SE's habit of killing new discussion than the people who are trying to make discussion.

Comment: @ReiMiyasaka, I guess you're right considering this question is from 2011, my answer from 2015 and here we are talking about is 7 years later

Answer (score 24):

Now is possible to use `-progress -` to print friendly info formatted by `key=value`.

```
ffmpeg  -i video.mp4 .......-s 1920x1080 -progress - -y out.mp4

speed=5.75x
frame=697
fps=167.7
stream_0_0_q=39.0
bitrate=2337.0kbits/s
total_size=6979778
out_time_ms=23893333
out_time=00:00:23.893333
dup_frames=0
drop_frames=0
```

Comment: Good to know. I wonder why this is not mentioned in the [docs](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html).

Comment: This is good! The reason the "-progress -" isn't mentioned in the docs is because "-" just means pipe it to stdout

Comment: does it also print duration?

Comment: To have just progress it's good to add `-v quiet` or `-v error` to prevent "contaminating" the stdout with other logs.

Answer (score 13):

You could try [`ffprobe`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html#SEC7). The correct command to get JSON output should look like the following:

```
ffprobe ... -print_format json
```

Comment: I compiled the newest ffmpeg but the json output of the program is only `{}`. It doesn't seems to work with the video files I have...

Comment: @JBernardo Hey, in case anyone else runs into this, you have to do -print_format rather then -of or else it will just do a very unhelpful { ... normal print output here ... }, see the accepted answer for an example command line

Answer (score 6):

Another usage of `ffprobe` which is nicely parseable:

```
ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=width,height,r_frame_rate,bit_rate,codec_name,duration -of csv=p=0:s=x video.mp4
```

results in:

`h264x600x480x25/1x385.680000x542326`

`-select_streams v:0` selects only the first video stream. If you remove that parameter you get one line for each stream.

Comment: The `s=x` sets the character that separates the fields when using `csv` output format. Useful for [asking for `width,height` to get output like `1280x720`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29585066/). Pretty ugly otherwise. Default is a comma if you remove `:s=x`, or you can always use a different [`-of` type](https://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html#Writers) such as json.