# Ffprobe with print json doesn't print anything

Tags: python, ubuntu, ffmpeg, ffprobe

I am trying to get information about a movie (resolution, frame rate, bit rate, codecs, duration etc) in a human readable way. I found this commnad:

```
ffprobe -v quiet -print_format json -show_format -show_streams somefile.asf
```

In this Stack Overflow question: [Get ffmpeg information in friendly way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7708373/get-ffmpeg-information-in-friendly-way)

But it doesn't work for me. When I try it in a  terminal, the output is empty:

```
richard@richard-desktop:~/projects/hello-python$ ffprobe -v quiet -print_format json -show_format -show_streams tests/test_1.mpg 
richard@richard-desktop:~/projects/hello-python$
```

Comment: Take out ``-v quiet`` and see what it says

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok, the current version of ffmpeg in Ubuntu repos is not up to date.

What I did was I added this more up to date repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jon-severinsson/ffmpeg
```

And then did:

```
sudo apt-get remove ffmpeg
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

And voila. It works and I get correct JSON output from ffprobe :)