# How to do a video player frontend for videos stored in server?

Tags: php, video, mp4

I am working on a project where I need to come up with a web UI for user-training videos. I have a collection of videos stored on a server as mp4 files. Since these videos are internal to the company, I could not share it on public sites like youtube/vimeo. That is the reason I am trying to come up with a simple interface to display the videos as thumbnails and open a pop-up player.

How can I do that with PHP? Any suggestions would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For thumbnails you can take a deeper look into `ffmepg` and `ffprobe`. You can make Screenshots and extract info with the help of it.

[Get ffmpeg information in friendly way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7708373/get-ffmpeg-information-in-friendly-way)

With the help of `shell_exec` you can start it with php.

You could do a Cronjob, which saves the information of new videos in the Database, so the Frontend User, can get the information quickly without waiting 5 seconds or more for pageload.

For the Video it self, i think you should google for

`html 5 video control`

Take a look into this Blog Post:

http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/building-custom-controls-for-html5-videos