# Organizing music files from online

Tags: database, upload, mp3

I am building a website which i would be uploading songs to my database. I am planning to upload the songs manually while another thought came into mind if there was a way to crawl online and get the songs. Is there a way that can be possible? I have looped through stack overflow and find no solution to this. Any help on organization songs would be appreciated. API's are out of my line for now.

Answer (score 1):

There are actually many sites that do this.  What you need to do is build a regular crawler that crawls links off web pages.  When you hit a URL that has the content type of media files (such as `audio/mpeg` for MP3 files), then download it.

Once you have the media file, [use FFprobe to get the metadata](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8191228/362536), and store this in your database along with the URL.

An alternative to all of this is let Google figure it out for you.  You can actually search for audio content types.