# FFProbe to Get Codec

Tags: php, ffmpeg, ffprobe

I've tried a bunch of different examples of getting a video's codec using FFProbe, [including this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8191228/2101328) and just can't get any output other than an occasional `[/STREAM]`.

This is what I'm currently trying

```
$codec = exec("ffprobe -v error -show_entries -show_streams stream=codec_name {$input['filename']}");
```

Tried this too...

```
$codec = exec("ffprobe -v quiet -print_format json -show_format -show_streams {$input['filename']}");
```

I know the video is good and it's working on the CLI, because when I use the following to get the duration I get the expected result

```
$duration = exec("ffprobe {$input['filename']} -show_format 2>&1 | sed -n 's/duration=//p'");
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Figured it out.

```
$codec = exec("ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=codec_name -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 {$input['filename']}");
```

`echo $codec;`

produces

`h264`

Answer (score 1):

A great answer from timgavin, Thank You!

My requirement meant I needed a little different application, I used Command Prompt:

```
set probe="<YOUR PATH>/ffmpeg/bin/ffprobe.exe"
%probe% -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=codec_name -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 input.avi
```

which in this case, returns:

```
mpeg4
```

Not sure this will be enough to for fill my requirements. HTML5 Video Tag is a poorly documented standard from my current research?

Thanks to @llogan comment, and more research, I have decided to post what I have found on the Video Tag:

```
ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe" -i input.avi -b 1500k -vcodec libx264 "output.mp4"
```

or

```
ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe -i input.mov -vcodec h264 -acodec aac -strict -2 output.mp4
```

Of course, the:

```
h264
```

Video codec is the only codec of the .mp4 Mime File Type that is supported. This guide may be of use: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264

As far as I can tell, if the Browser one is using, is up to date, it should support these Video Mime Types!

Thanks to @llogan 's advice, we no longer need:

```
-strict -2
```

but use:

```
-movflags +faststart
```

What I have now, thanks to lloyd's help and research is:

```
string ffmpeg = "Utils/ffmpeg/ffmpeg.exe";
string encode = "-y -i \"" + InputFile + "\" -movflags +faststart -vcodec libx264 -crf 22 -acodec aac -b:a 192k \"" + OutputFile + "\"";
```

Where: `OutputFile` is OutputFile.mp4

As of: 06.12.2020 this is a good ffmpeg encoding for the HTML5 Video Tag.

Comment: mpeg4 is MPEG-4 Part 2 video which is not supported by HTML5 video.

Comment: Yes, understand this: h264 appears to be, but must be in .mp4 Mime Type.

Comment: No need for `-strict -2` unless your ffmpeg is from 2015 or older. You can add `-movflags +faststart` so it can begin playback faster.

Comment: @llogan Thank You! I was looking for documentation and could not see any.