# ffmpeg mov to mp4: not fast enough

Tags: react-native, ffmpeg

I have a react native app in which users can take a video. I limited the duration of the video to max 30 seconds (for storage purposes). On iOS, a video is in the mov-format. On android, the video is in mp4-format.

For easy use, I convert the mov-file on ios to mp4 using ffmpeg. This is my command:

```
-i video.mov -preset ultrafast -vcodec h264 -acodec aac video.mp4
```

I was testing this, and everything works as expected, but converting a 30 second video almost takes to minutes, even with the `-preset ultrafast` flag.

A possible improvement would be copying the audio (`-c:a copy`) instead of re-encoding it, but I don't think it would be *much* faster.

Size is about 50mb for a 30 second movie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the MOV contains video and audio comaptible with MP4 then just re-mux (no re-encoding):

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -c copy output.mp4
```

Comment: How can I check if the MOV contains video and audio compatible with mp4? Anyway, I'll give it a try! Thank you for your response!

Comment: @yesterday You can run `ffmpeg -i input.mov` and it will output info about the video and audio. If the video is `h264` or `hevc` and the audio is `aac` then it will work for you.

Comment: I did not know that command. Thank you! I was reading up on the internet and it seems that MOV and MP4 are quite similar, I did not know that.

Comment: @yesterday Yes, they are related, but MP4 does not support as many formats as MOV. If you need to automate/script the format check you can use `ffprobe`. [See Is there a way to use ffmpeg to determine the encoding of a file before transcoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35280871/)