# How to find duration of a video file using mediainfo in seconds or other formats?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, multimedia, ffprobe, mediainfo

How can I find duration of a video file in miliseconds i.e. in integer in deterministic way.
I have used ffprobe to get the duration but it doesn't give duration for all file formats.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use the following commands:

i) To get the duration of video stream:

```
$ mediainfo --Inform="Video;%Duration%"  [inputfile]
```

ii) To get the duration of the media file:

```
$ mediainfo --Inform="General;%Duration%" [inputfile]
```

iii) To get the duration of audio stream only:

```
$ mediainfo --Inform="Audio;%Duration%" [inputfile]
```

iv) To get values of more than one parameter:

```
$ mediainfo --Inform="Video;%Width%,%Height%,%BitRate%,%FrameRate%" [inputfile]
```

Output would be something like this:

```
1280,720,3000000,30.0
```

Answer (score 17):

As offered by *iota* to use `mediainfo --Inform="Video;%Duration%"  [inputfile]`, possible but returns weird results.

For example, for video with duration *31s 565ms* the output of given command would be:

```
31565
```

It wasn't suitable for me and I came up to the following solution:

```
mediainfo --Inform="Video;%Duration/String3%" inputExample.webm
```

Returned value is:

```
00:00:31.565
```

After all, you could just format returned value with, let's say *PHP*, to convert it to *seconds*, e.g.:

```
$parsed = date_parse( '00:00:31.565' );
echo $parsed['hour'] * 3600 + $parsed['minute'] * 60 + $parsed['second'];
```

<kbd>[**Example**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/u9u1U4)</kbd>

Answer (score 4):

I use the below command on my xubuntu machine and it does exactly what the OP wants to accomplish.

```
mediainfo --Output="Video;%Duration%\n" *.mp4 | awk '{ sum += $1 } END { secs=sum/1000; h=int(secs/3600);m=int((secs-h*3600)/60);s=int(secs-h*3600-m*60); printf("%02d:%02d:%02d\n",h,m,s) }'
```

Answer (score 1):

we can also use ffmpeg to get the duration of any video or audio files.

To install ffmpeg follow this [link](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu)

```
import subprocess
import re

process = subprocess.Popen(['ffmpeg',  '-i', path_of_media_file], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
matches = re.search(r"Duration:\s{1}(?P<hours>\d+?):(?P<minutes>\d+?):(?P<seconds>\d+\.\d+?),", stdout, re.DOTALL).groupdict()

print matches['hours']
print matches['minutes']
print matches['seconds']
```

Comment: Nice, it is same as ffprobe which I found, supports lesser formats than mediainfo. 
And mediainfo is made specifically for these purposes however whole ffmpeg framework is built for transcoding and heavy to install .