# Creating 3 Column CSV have FileName Duration Size in CMD

Tags: batch-file, cmd, mediainfo

I am using builtin cmd commands & `mediainfo` utility to get three parameters for media filenames stored in a TXT file but help will be appreciated as I can't make it work

From here I scrapped code for mediainfo: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19091772/1162750

my code is

```
@echo off
cls
if exist mediafiles.txt del mediafiles.txt
dir /s/b . > mediafiles.txt
for /F "tokens=*" %%i in  (mediafiles.txt) do  (
    set /a dur=mediainfo --Inform="Video;%Duration%" "%%i"
    set /a mins=(%dur%/1000)/60
    set size=%%~zi
    set /a MB=(%size%/1024)/1024
    echo %%i,%mins%,%MB% >> mediafiles.csv
)
@echo on
```

FileDuration is being converted to minutes from milliseconds (default mediainfo output) & FileSize in MBs

Comment: You need to invoke delayedexpansion [hundreds of SO articles about that - use the search feature] in order to display or use the run-time value of any variable that's changed within a parenthesised series of instructions (aka "code block").

Comment: Please take the [tour], read [Ask] and [MCVE].  "I can't make it work" is not a good problem statement and definitely not a question.  What exactly isn't working?  What does the script do and what did you expect it to do?

Comment: this line `set /a dur=mediainfo --Inform="Video;%Duration%" "%%i"` throws error `Missing Operator`

Answer (score 0):

`set /a dur=mediainfo --Inform="Video;%Duration%" "%%i"` doesn't work. To get the output of a command, use a `for /f` loop:

```
for "delims=" %%a in ('mediainfo --Inform="Video;%Duration%" "%%i"') do set "dur=%%A"
```

(assuming, you have a variable `%Duration%`; If you need `%Duration%` literal, double the percent signs:

```
for "delims=" %%a in ('mediainfo --Inform="Video;%%Duration%%" "%%i"') do set "dur=%%A"
```