# How to find Video Codec for file ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm working with HLS streams of MPEGTS that contains H264.

When I look at the HLS Playlist given by the server, it specifies that the codec is `avc1.77.30,mp4a.40.2`

Here's a snippet from the file

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1787760,CODECS="avc1.77.30,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=640x360
```

Is there a way I can retrieve this information from `ffmpeg`?

I found a question that was asked before [How to determine video codec of a file with FFmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2869281/how-to-determine-video-codec-of-a-file-with-ffmpeg)

But the closest I can seem to get to any of their outputs is `h264` and not `avc1.77.30`

The playlist contains 7 MPEG-TS files, I've tried using `ffprobe` on both the playlist file, as well as the individual video files, but they both seem to report the parser, not the encoding of the actual video.

Answer (score 2):

The string `avc1.77.30,mp4a.40.2` describes the codecs of the video and audio stream as per [RFC 6381 section 3.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6381#section-3.3).

In `avc1.77.30`, `avc1` identifies the codec, also known as H.264 which you've already recognized. `77` is the decimal representation of `Main profile`, usually written as hex `4d`. `30` is 10 times the level, which is `3.0`.

```
ffprobe -select_streams v -show_entries stream=codec_name,profile,level INPUT
```

will print out this info. The level is reported as its 10x value.

`mp4a.40.2` stands for AAC audio codec with LC profile. For which, use

```
ffprobe -select_streams a -show_entries stream=codec_name,profile INPUT
```

Comment: When I run `ffprobe` with the arguments above it just says `profile=High` is there a way to get the number instead?