# How to handle error when exit code is zero in bash

Tags: bash, shell, colors, terminal, pygments

I have the following script `~/bin/cat` that uses `pygmentize` to display syntax highlightable files when ever possible if not just regular old `cat`.

```
#!/bin/bash

for var; do 
    pygmentize "$var" 2> /dev/null

    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then 
        /bin/cat "$var"
    fi
done
```

This works fine on my work machine but not on my home machine. At home if `pygmentize` doesn't recognize a file it displays the same error message but the exit status is 0 where as at work it returns 1, which breaks the script. The only difference being at work I run Fedora and at home Ubuntu.

```
$ pygmentize testfile
Error: no lexer for filename 'testfile' found

$ echo $?
0

$ file testfile
file: ASCII text
```

This is strange as both are the same version

```
$ pygmentize -V
Pygments version 1.4, (c) 2006-2008 by Georg Brandl.
```

I could `grep` for `Error` in `stderr` but how do I do this without throwing away `stdout`, How should I handle this?

Comment: Look through the patches that both distributions apply and figure out which fixes/breaks it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, your best approach is to fix `pygmentize` to properly return an error code. As Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams mentions, one of the distros has a patch that is either causing or fixing this.

But, here is how to work around it:

### If the error message is on stderr

The easiest way is probably to redirect stderr to a temporary file, and leave stdout alone:

```
pygmentize "$var" 2> "$tmpfile"
```

then you can grep `"$tmpfile"`. There are other ways, but they're [more complicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3618078/pipe-only-stderr-through-a-filter).

### If the error message is on stdout

Yep, that'd be another bug in pygmentize, it should be on stderr. The temporary file will work again, however. Just `cat` the temporary file back to stdout if its OK. Alternatively, you can use `tee` to duplicate the stdout to several destinations.

Comment: The error message is on `stderr` at least but I don't really want want to create tmp files everytime I cat something. I guess I should look into fixing pygmentize and not a work around.

Comment: @sudo_O Well, check the 'more complicated' link... you can do that whole sequence of redirects and avoid the temp file. But yeah, really, you should fix the program. And please once you find the fix, submit a patch to Ubuntu so others can benefit, too.