# How pipe std and err output to separate commands in bash script?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a bash script executing a long run command. I want to prefix each line printed by the command to stdout with $stdprefix and each line printed to stderr with $errprefix.

I don't want to store output to variables or even worse to files, because I'd have to wait until the command finishes execution to see the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
# your prefixes
stdprefix="stdout: "
errprefix="stderr: "

# sample command to produce output and error
cmd() { echo 'output'; echo >&2 'error'; }
```

Now to redirect stdout and stderr independently:

```
{ cmd 2>&3 | awk -v p="$stdprefix" '{print p $0}'; } 3>&1 1>&2 |
  awk -v p="$errprefix" '{print p $0}'
stderr: error
stdout: output
```

Just replace `cmd` with your long running command.

Comment: Thank you. I would also redirect output of second awk to stderr. It would look like this:
{ cmd 2>&3 | awk -v p="$stdprefix" '{print p $0}'; } 3>&1 1>&2 | awk -v p="$errprefix" '{print p $0}' >&2

Comment: That redirect I proposed in my previous comment prints **everything** to stderr. Anyway during studying your answer I found this http://stackoverflow.com/a/3618208/3087441 which works like a charm. So my final code is `cmd 2> >( sed 's/^/$errprefix/' >&2 ) | sed 's/^/$stdprefix/'`

Comment: Yes you can use process substitution also but make sure you redirect stderr before stdout using that. Basically `cmd 2> >(stderr_handler)  | stdout_handler` form.