# Is there a way to use Helm 3's new library charts without needing to involve `helm dependency update`?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

The use case is as follows:

```
overall-concern/
  charts/
    cloudformation-chart/
    kubernetes-chart/
    shared-library/
```

Both the Cloudformation and Kubernetes charts rely on the shared library. If I specify
it as a dependency in those charts, however, I need to do `helm dependency update` and
it will be copied into those charts' `charts/` subdirectory and a `Chart.lock` file will
be generated. That seems unnecessary.

On the other hand, if I symlink the chart:

```
overall-concern/
  cloudformation-chart/
    charts/
      shared-library -> ../../shared-library
```

It *works*, but I receive a warning when running `helm template` that there are symlinks
in the path, leading me to think that this is not intended or is otherwise deprecated:

```
walk.go:74: found symbolic link in path: ... (paths elided) ...
```

Is there a blessed solution that will let me use a local chart without treating it as
a formal "dependency" in Helm 3?

Comment: I've found [this commit](https://github.com/helm/helm/commit/5a7d4f1f748afcbe9c714c1ce35cef7395a157f8#diff-5bd89f2e733a8bb8d60a9cb4947cf0f0R74) which seems to just add info when loading irregular files, so you can use symlinks as you already do and all should be fine

Comment: Thanks, @HelloWorld, good catch. I've opened [an issue](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/7019) against the Helm repository. Hopefully there will be some clarification.

Comment: I'm with you.  Symlinks are better in a monolith chart repo.  Here is how I eat that warning `helm upgrade ... 2> >(grep -v 'found symbolic link' >&2)` per https://stackoverflow.com/a/52575213/207353