# Customised redirection of stderr?

Tags: linux, stderr, unix-text-processing

I know that I can redirect the standard error output stream by:
*$ ./my-C-binary 2>error.log*

What if I want to ignore the first two characters of anything from stderr before writing to the file? I've searched but I can't seem to find a way to do so. I'm not allowed to re-build my-C-binary (i.e. not allowed to change the source code). I am also not allowed to write an additional program to help with the task, it **must** be solved with a single command line to modify the *2>error.log* portion. I don't know how to do that even after a few days of searching and trying.

Let's say the output of stderr is:

*The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.*

The text in error.log must be:

*e quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.*

Thanks in advance for any suggestions and help.

Comment: Depending on your operating system there might be commands that you can use in a pipe to remove the two first characters of the program output.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks for the reply. I'm on ubuntu 20.04, could you elaborate with an example?

Comment: `cut`, `sed`, `perl`, `awk` should do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52575087/3150802) using process substitution to redirect stderr in bash with @Someprogrammerdude's use of `tail`:

`./my-C-binary 2> >(tail -c +3 > error.log)`

As an aside, note the "+3" parameter to tail: The number indicates the 1-based index of the character where output starts; if you want to skip the first two characters, you start with the third.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in reply. I although I had to make slight modifications to make it work for the situation I'm tackling, your answer got me 90% of the way.  The link you've provided to process substitution and other articles related to the topic quickly got me up to speed with how to resolve it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can pipe the output through the [`tail`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tail.1.html) command to ask it to skip the first two bytes:

```
$ ./my-C-binary |& tail -c +2 >error.log
```

Unfortunately this will pipe *both* standard error and standard output. To only get standard error, you need to do it in two steps:

1. Run the program like you do now, redirecting standard error to its file
2. Modify the file to "remove" the two first characters

Comment: This redirects stdout, not stderr.  To pipe stderr, you'll need a `2>&1` before the `|`, but that will pipe both stdout and stderr, so you might want a `>file` before *that* to send stderr somewhere else first

Comment: Although it didn't solve the issue I was facing, it made me think more about other syntax that I could use if the situation was different. Thanks for taking the time to reply and try to help me! It led me to read more about different cases.