# How to timestamp only stderr from cron job and send to file?

Tags: cron

I have a cron job that runs a python script and writes *only* the stderr to a log file.

```
* * * * * python /home/hydro/cron.py 2>> /home/hydro/uhoh.log
```

What I want is a timestamp for each line it appends to the log file. I'm struggling with figuring out how to do this with only stderr; I have found multiple solutions that handle both stderr and stdout with `2>&1`, but that's not what I want. I followed [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/117360/sending-cron-output-to-a-file-with-a-timestamp-in-its-name) to try out something like this:

timestamp.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
while read x; do
    echo -n `date +%d/%m/%Y\ %H:%M:%S`;
    echo -n " ";
    echo $x;
done
```

My cron job:

```
* * * * * python /home/hydro/cron.py 2 | /home/hydro/timestamp.sh >> /home/hydro/uhoh.log
```

This mails the error and creates an `uhoh.log` file but writes nothing to it. This is what I got mailed...

```
/home/hydro/timestamp.sh: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `most'
/home/hydro/timestamp.sh: line 1: `Traceback (most recent call last):'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hydro/cron.py", line 2, in <module>
    x = 10/0
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
Exception ignored in: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='utf-8'>
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

I tried this too:

```
* * * * * python /home/hydro/cron.py 2> | /home/hydro/timestamp.sh >> /home/hydro/uhoh.log
```

This produces a syntax error that gets mailed to me. No `uhoh.log` gets produced.

Is what I want possible or does the stderr have to be combined with the stdout?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pipe only STDERR through a filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3618078/pipe-only-stderr-through-a-filter)

Comment: @Ouroborus Potentially, but for a linux novice like myself I find those answers difficult to comprehend. I think the solution I arrived at (posted below) is perhaps a bit simpler (or at least more clearly explained in various threads in stackoverflow/google).

Answer (score 0):

The solution I arrived at:

```
* * * * * python /home/hydro/cron.py 2>&1 1>/dev/null | /home/hydro/timestamp.sh >> /home/hydro/uhoh.log
```

This will redirect stderr to the same place stdout is going. It then redirects stdout into the "blackhole" that is /dev/null. That means only stderr is left, which gets piped to my timestamp script and finally appended to the log file. I end up with the stderr sent to my log file and neither stderr or stdout is sent to mail.

From this [link](https://www.brianstorti.com/understanding-shell-script-idiom-redirect/#:%7E:text=At%20this%20point%20you%20probably,we%20are%20redirecting%20the%20stdout%20%E2%80%9D.), explaining what `2>&1` does:

> A file descriptor is nothing more that a positive integer that represents an open file.

> ...there are file descriptors for the Standard Output (stdout) and Standard Error (stderr).

> In plain English, it means that there are “ids” that identify these two locations, and it will always be 1 for stdout and 2 for stderr.

> 1 is just the file descriptor for stdout. The syntax for redirecting is [FILE_DESCRIPTOR]>, leaving the file descriptor out (>) is just a shortcut to 1>.

> ...to redirect stderr, it should be just a matter of adding the right file descriptor in place

> You use &1 to reference the value of the file descriptor 1 (stdout). So when you use 2>&1 you are basically saying “Redirect the stderr to the same place we are redirecting the stdout”.