# The shell redirection command used for creating file in another di

Tags: linux

I need to create a log report say .txt file in one directory that saves all the errors that raise after execution of a program which resides in another directory, so which shell command is used in linux.

Answer (score 0):

`./command > ./outfiles/out.file 2> ./errfiles/err.file` should do the trick for you.

Sort of answered at: [How to pipe stderr, and not stdout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342826/how-to-pipe-stderr-and-not-stdout) but that questioner wanted a pipe.