# Write output to file with tabs/text added in ksh script

Tags: shell, unix, logging, scripting, ksh

I am writing a KornShell (ksh) script that is logging to a file. I am redirecting the output of one of my commands (scp) to the same file, but I would like to add a tab at the start of those lines in the log file if possible.

Is this possible to do?

EDIT: Also I should mention that the text I am redirecting is coming from stderr. My line currently looks like this:

```
scp -q ${wks}:${file_location} ${save_directory} >> ${script_log} 2>&1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: the below doesn't work for `ksh` (see [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/26566/16669) for possible solutions).

---

You probably can do something like

```
my_command | sed 's/^/\t/' >> my.log
```

The idea is to process the output of the command with a stream editor like `sed` in some manner. In this case, a tab will be added at the beginning of every line. Consider:

```
$ echo -e 'Test\nfoobar' | sed 's/^/\t/'
    Test
    foobar
```

I haven't tested this in `ksh`, but a quick web search suggests that it should work.

Also note that some commands can write to both `stdout` and `stderr`, don't forget to handle it.

**Edit:** in response to the comment and the edit in the question, the adjusted command can look like

```
scp -q ${wks}:${file_location} ${save_directory} 2>&1 | \
    sed 's/^/\t/' >> ${script_log}
```

or, if you want to get rid of `stdout` completely,

```
scp -q ${wks}:${file_location} ${save_directory} 2>&1 >/dev/null | \
    sed 's/^/\t/' >> ${script_log}
```

The technique is described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2342841/1258041).

Comment: Ah yes, you bring up another point I forgot to mention. The text I am logging is coming from stderr.  Will that make a difference in how I implement this?

Comment: @MasterZ You just have to adjust the redirections. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2342826/1258041), for example.

Comment: I modified my code to take into account the link you gave but now that part of the script does not run at all and I get the error "Unrecognized Command: /^/\t/"... I edited my original question with the code I am using if that helps.

Comment: @MasterZ The problem seems to be in the call to `sed`. Can you show how you use it?

Comment: Thanks for adding the code to your answer.  I'm glad to see I was not too far off in how I was testing this, I just forgot the s/ in the sed.  But, it is not yet 100%.  a "t" is added to the beginning of the line instead of a tab.

Comment: @MasterZ Does adding `$` help? `sed $'s/^/\t/'`

Comment: No, using the $ did not help. Also using multiple back slashes did not help either.

Comment: @MasterZ See the link I added at the top of my answer. It's basically to an identical question, and that one has answers working on `ksh`.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I used the awk command listed in that link "awk '{print "\t" $0}' and it worked great.