# Redirect standard error to a string in C

Tags: c, string, stderr, io-redirection

I would like to be able to redirect stderr to a C string because I need to use the string in the program I'm writing.
I would like to avoid writing to a file (on the hard drive) first then readings the file to get the string.
What is the best way to get this done?

Answer (score 15):

You could just use [setbuf()](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/setbuf.3.html) to change `stderr`'s buffer:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char buf[BUFSIZ];
    setbuf(stderr, buf);
    fprintf(stderr, "Hello, world!\n");
    printf("%s", buf);
    return 0;
}
```

prints:

```
Hello, world! 
Hello, world!
```

Note: you should change the buffer before any operation on the stream.

Comment: Oh nice! Didn't know you could even do that! Is `BUFSIZ` defined in stdio?

Comment: @mtahmed yes, there's more info in the man page, you could also set the buffering mode if you use `setvbuf()`

Comment: Is there a way to get a callback when 'buf' is written to?

Comment: @user1660675 not that I know of, maybe if you use select on the fd not sure.

Comment: -1 because this is a hack.  The buffer used by `setbuf` is for use by the framework only. This works only if (a) you call `setbuf` immediately the `fprintf`, and your string fits entirely in `BUFSIZ` (or maybe even limited to `BUFSIZ/2` if the buffer is used as a ping-pong, depends on dark implementation details of stdio).

Comment: I don't think this will work with sub processes, ie. `system("/bin/echo foo > /dev/stderr");`, because you are only changing the buffering for the *stream* interface to stderr, and not the actual `stderr` file descriptor.

Comment: How can I prevent fprintf call to be printed out to the console in this example?

Answer (score 2):

1. Redirect stderr to stdout and pipe to your C program.  See [How to pipe stderr, and not stdout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342826/how-to-pipe-stderr-and-not-stdout)
2. Read from stdin in your C program, of course.

This is assuming stderr is coming from another program.  If you want to capture all stderr output from your program and process, then in a separate thread listen for writes to stderr via `fopen("/dev/stderr", "r")`.

Comment: I'll give this a shot.
I am trying to capture stderr from within the program and use it within that same program so, I would use fopen on stderr then redirect to stdout?

Answer (score -1):

I gave an solution using C++ to redirect stdout and stderr to a function (called for each line).  I know this was tagged as C, but the guts of my solution use the POSIX api.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/25087408/364818