# How to redirect stderr and std::cerr to a stringstream?

Tags: c++, stderr

The library 'libmodbus' is a C library that uses `fprintf(stderr, "")` to send debug information to the console. Capturing this text continuously for use within my C++ application has been a challenge.

This post explains how to perform this in C++ with just a few lines:

[redirect stdout/stderr to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419356/redirect-stdout-stderr-to-a-string)

But, after attempting this, I could not get it to work. Calls to `std::cerr` were captured, but calls to `fprintf(stderr, "")` were unaffected.

Doing the same in C is not as easy. As explained in this post, one can assign a `char[]` for `stderr` to be written to:

[Redirect standard error to a string in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14715493/redirect-standard-error-to-a-string-in-c)

Working with `setbuf(stderr, char[], size)`, and the text being stored in it, is not documented very well. The standard calls to `fgetch`, `fread` and `fscanf` all return -1, with no error message. I attribute this to the fact that `stderr` is write only and reading from it will fail.

I tried opening the file handle with each option, some would allow write access, but none allowed read access. Using the debugger and stepping through the code one line at a time was the only way I found to solve this problem.

Using "Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Current Version 17.1.2"

As data is pushed into the `char[]`, no null termination is added, but by using `fgetpos`, the terminator can be placed in the correct spot.

I have almost completed a class which can perform this function. I have not found documentation of how to reassign `stderr` back to the console. It just feels incomplete without restoring everything back to the way it was.

After a long search, I thought it appropriate to ask:

1. How do I restore `stderr` back to the console after a call to `freopen("nul", "a", stderr)`?
2. Did I completely overlook a simple way to do this?
3. How portable will this solution be?

I'm forced to meddle with the inner workings of my *current* tool chains libraries. No good can come from that.

```cpp
/* fstream_redirect.h */
#ifndef FSTREAM_REDIRECT_H
#define FSTREAM_REDIRECT_H
    #include <iostream>
    #include <sstream>
    #include "stdio.h"
    

    char fstream_redirect_buffer[BUFSIZ+1];

    class fstream_redirect {
    public:
        fstream_redirect(std::stringstream &new_buffer, std::ostream &fstream, FILE* c_handle){
            
            //save the pointers needed later
            _new_buffer = &new_buffer;
            _old        = fstream.rdbuf();
            _fstream    = &fstream;

            //Direct C++ calls to std::cout, std::cin, or std::cerr to a new_buffer
            fstream.rdbuf(new_buffer.rdbuf());


            //Direct C calls to stdout, stdin, or stderr to a new_buffer. 
            //This is not easy in C, as it is in C++
            // Order of Operations
            // 1) check buffer for change
            // 2) null terminate the new data
            // 3) retrive data
            // 4) rewind file handle to begining
            // 5) GoTo step 1

            //send stream to a void so it does not print
            #ifdef _WIN32
                _file = freopen("nul", "a", c_handle);
            #else
                _file = freopen("/dev/null", "a", c_handle);
            #endif  
            //set the _file to use our temp buffer
            if( setvbuf( _file, fstream_redirect_buffer, _IOFBF, BUFSIZ) )
                std::cout << "setvbuf failed";
        }

        ~fstream_redirect() {
            //C++ restore the stream to the correct output.
            _fstream->rdbuf(_old);
            //C figure out how to restore the stream to the proper output
            //  <<<< HERE IS WHERE YOU CAN HELP >>>>
        }

        void update(){
            fpos_t pos;
            char *p = fstream_redirect_buffer;
            fgetpos(_file, &pos);
            //Poll the C buffer for new data
            if(pos){
                p[pos] = 0;             //null terminate the data
                *_new_buffer << p;      //send data to the new_buffer
                rewind(_file);          //reset the next write to the start of the buffer       
            }
        }

    private:
        fstream_redirect() {};
        std::stringstream*  _new_buffer;
        std::streambuf*     _old;
        std::ios*           _fstream;
        FILE*               _file;
    };

#endif
```

```
/* main.cpp */
#include "fstream_redirect.h"

std::stringstream           _gError_buffer;
fstream_redirect            _gError_redirect( _gError_buffer, std::cerr, stderr );

int main(){
    fprintf(stderr, "1");
    std::cerr << "2";
    fprintf(stderr, "3");
    std::cerr << "4";
    fprintf(stderr, "5");
    std::cerr << "6";

    std::cout << _gError_buffer.str() << std::endl; //OUTPUT '246'
    _gError_redirect.update();
    std::cout << _gError_buffer.str() << std::endl; //OUTPUT '246135'
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Interesting question. Hope you get an answer because it would be a good tool to have in the box. Totally unrelated note: `__FSTREAM_REDIRECT_H__` is an illegal identifier unless you're writing the compiler or it's Standard Library implementation. [Details](https://stackoverflow.com/q/228783/4581301). Breaking the underscore rules doesn't bite all that often, but when it does bite, the results can be utterly baffling.

Comment: Maybe use `dup` similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908687/how-to-redirect-the-output-back-to-the-screen-after-freopenout-txt-a-stdo

Comment: I never knew there where underscore rules for the include names. Good to know

Comment: @Nor There are no rules prohibiting underscores in the names of files you `#include`. `__FSTREAM_REDIRECT_H__` is a reserved identifier though.