# How does cmd > /dev/null 2>&1 work?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I'm reading up on redirecting data to `/dev/null` and so I tried a simple test:

```
ping a.b.c  # which results in an address not found
```

If I try this:

```
ping a.b.c > /dev/null # prints the same error message as the one above
```

However, if I do this:

```
ping a.b.c > /dev/null 2>&1 # The error message is gone
```

That last solution is the desired solution, but what is happening with this `2>&1`?  My research so far suggest that `2` represents `stderr` and `1` represents `stdout`.  So if I read it that way, it looks like I'm creating a `stderr` file and redirecting `stdout` to it?

If that is the case, what does the `&` in that command do?

Comment: & lets bash know that `1` is not a filename, but `stderr`. Btw you don't have to use `|`, `ping a.b.c 2>/dev/null` or `ping a.b.c &>/dev/null` should do that.

Comment: @jokester thanks!  So if `1` is not a file name, what is it?  Just memory?

Comment: You should be getting "/dev/null: Permission denied", since you're trying to execute `/dev/null` as a command. It should be `> /dev/null`, not `| /dev/null`.

Comment: @KeithThompson you're right!  Minor typo.  I'll edit.

Comment: @jokester ignore my comment I understand now.

Comment: @nkon They call it [file descriptor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor), and shell uses the same convension.

Comment: Note that you could write: `ping abc.example.com 2>/dev/null` to throw the error messages away without throwing away standard output.

Comment: This is close to a duplicate of [How to pipe stderr and not stdout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342826/how-to-pipe-stderr-and-not-stdout/), but the mention of 'pipe' indicates that it is not identical.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are right, `2` is `STDERR`, `1` is `STDOUT`. When you do `2>&1` you are saying: "print to `STDOUT` (`1`) the things that would go to `STDERR` (`2`)". And before that, you said your `STDOUT` would go to `/dev/null`. Therefore, nothing is seen. In the examples 1 and 2 you get the output message because it is being printed to `STDERR`, as a regular redirection only redirects `STDOUT`.

And when you do the redirection, you are not creating a `STDERR`, the processes always have a `STDERR` and a `STDOUT` when they are created.

Comment: @nkon If you want, you can actually _see_ which file descriptors are attached to a process. To do that, find the pid--e.g., `pgrep firefox`. Then `ls -l /proc/<pid>/fd` -- notice that the fds are actually represented as symbolic links in the directory! I still find all this fascinating and I've been running Debian since 2002.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the following code which prints the word "stdout" to stdout and the word "stderror" to stderror.

```
$ (echo "stdout"; echo "stderror" >&2)
stdout
stderror
```

Note that the '&' operator tells bash that 2 is a file descriptor (which points to the stderr) and not a file name. If we left out the '&', this command would print `stdout` to stdout, and create a file named "2" and write `stderror` there.

By experimenting with the code above, you can see for yourself exactly how redirection operators work. For instance, by changing which file which of the two descriptors 1,2, is redirected to `/dev/null` the following two lines of code delete everything from the stdout, and everything from stderror respectively (printing what remains).

```
$ (echo "stdout"; echo "stderror" >&2) 1>/dev/null
stderror
$ (echo "stdout"; echo "stderror" >&2) 2>/dev/null
stdout
```

Now, we approach the crux of the question (substituting my example for yours), why does

```
(echo "stdout"; echo "stderror" >&2) >/dev/null 2>&1
```

produce no output? To truly understand this, I highly recommend you read this [webpage on file descriptor tables](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/bash-one-liners-explained-part-three/). Assuming you have done that reading, we can proceed. Note that Bash processes left to right; thus Bash sees `>/dev/null` first (which is the same as `1>/dev/null`), and sets the file descriptor 1 to point to /dev/null instead of the stdout. Having done this, Bash then moves rightwards and sees `2>&1`. This sets the file descriptor 2 **to point to the same file** as file descriptor 1 (and not to file descriptor 1 itself!!!! (see [this resource on pointers](http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/106/) for more info) . Since file descriptor 1 points to /dev/null, and  file descriptor 2 points to the same file as file descriptor 1, file descriptor 2 now also points to /dev/null. Thus both file descriptors point to /dev/null, and this is why no output is rendered.

---

To test if you really understand the concept, try to guess the output when we switch the redirection order:

```
(echo "stdout"; echo "stderror" >&2)  2>&1 >/dev/null
```

> stderror

The reasoning here is that evaluating from left to right, Bash sees 2>&1, and thus sets the file descriptor 2 to point to the same place as file descriptor 1, ie stdout. It then sets file descriptor 1 (remember that >/dev/null = 1>/dev/null) to point to >/dev/null, thus deleting everything which would usually be send to to the standard out. Thus all we are left with was that which was not send to stdout in the subshell (the code in the parentheses)- i.e. "stderror".
  The interesting thing to note there is that even though 1 is just a pointer to the stdout, redirecting pointer 2 to 1 via `2>&1` does NOT form a chain of pointers 2 -> 1 -> stdout. If it did, as a result of redirecting 1 to /dev/null, the code `2>&1 >/dev/null` would give the pointer chain 2 -> 1 -> /dev/null, and thus the code would generate nothing, in contrast to what we saw above.

---

Finally, I'd note that there is a simpler way to do this:

From section 3.6.4 [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html), we see that we can use the operator `&>` to redirect both stdout and stderr. Thus, to redirect both the stderr and stdout output of any command to `\dev\null` (which deletes the output), we simply type 
`$ command &> /dev/null` 
or in case of my example:

```
$ (echo "stdout"; echo "stderror" >&2) &>/dev/null
```

---

Key takeaways:

- File descriptors behave like pointers (although file descriptors are not the same as file pointers)
- Redirecting a file descriptor "a" to a file descriptor "b" which points to file "f", causes file descriptor "a" to point to the same place as file descriptor b - file "f". It DOES NOT form a chain of pointers a -> b -> f
- Because of the above, order matters, `2>&1 >/dev/null` is != `>/dev/null 2>&1`. One generates output and the other does not!

---

Finally have a look at these great resources:

[Bash Documentation on Redirection](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html), [An Explanation of File Descriptor Tables](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/bash-one-liners-explained-part-three/), [Introduction to Pointers](http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/106/)