# Send standard out and standard error to different files, but also display them

Tags: bash, redirectstandardoutput

The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7901517/how-to-redirect-stderr-and-stdout-to-different-files-in-the-same-line-of-bash) show us how to redirect standard output and standard error to two separate files.

But what if I also want to see the output on the console as it is created?

We can use `tee` to save one of the streams to a file, but then with the other stream, we must either echo it or save it to a file.

```
$ command 2>error.log | tee output.log
```

How can I use `tee` on both streams?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Send standard err to pipe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17222568/send-standard-err-to-pipe)

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17222568/send-standard-err-to-pipe#17226179).

```
$ ( command 2>&1 1>&3 | tee error.log >&2 ) 3>&1 | tee output.log
```

Comment: If you found the answer in another question, you should just mark this as a duplicate.

Comment: +1 Pretty sure this specific answer is more useful/easy to understand for what most users want to redirect to another fd for. And obviously answer's OP's own question, though maybe still a duplicate.