# How to make sure errors in pipes get reported

Tags: python, bash

I do a

```
python py_prog.py | java scalaProg.Pkg
```

The python program must fetch stuff from DB and pipe it to Scala program. We have centralized **error monitoring** for python BUT the scala program may **silently fail**. So if the Scala program fails, I want its stderr transferred to our monitoring system with a third program like this bash pseudocode:

```
(python py_prog.py | java scalaProg.Pkg) || python logging_program.py
```

(Writing `logging_program` and making it talk to our error monitoring is easy, setting up a similar system for the scala program is hard).

So how do I accomplish:

1. when scalaProg fails, pipe its stderr to a third program
2. handling `IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe` in py_prog when scalaProg fails

Comment: What does the error in `scalaProg` have to do with the `Broken pipe` error in `py_prog`?

Comment: It happens in a `sys.stdout.write()` because `scalaProg` has crashed

Answer (score 1):

With bash you could use process subtitution and you would still see the output of `java scalaProg.Pkg`:

```
python py_prog.py | java scalaProg.Pkg 2> >(python logging_program.py)
```

Or you could place it on tee to see stderr on the terminal as well:

```
python py_prog.py | java scalaProg.Pkg 2> >(tee >(python logging_program.py))
```

If it's the shell that runs `java scalaProg.Pkg` that sends the error message you could encapsulate it in a subshell to get the error as well:

```
python py_prog.py | (java scalaProg.Pkg;) 2> >(tee >(python logging_program.py))
```

If you need get everything (both stdout and stderr from `java scalaProg.Pkg` do this:

```
python py_prog.py | java scalaProg.Pkg > >(tee >(python logging_program.py)) 2>&1
```

Or this:

```
python py_prog.py | (java scalaProg.Pkg;) > >(tee >(python logging_program.py)) 2>&1
```

If you want to get all stdout and stderr both from `python py_prog.py` and `java scalaProg.Pkg` do this:

```
{python py_prog.py | java scalaProg.Pkg;} > >(tee >(python logging_program.py)) 2>&1
```

Or this which includes the error that might be generated from the calling shell as well:

```
(python py_prog.py | java scalaProg.Pkg;) > >(tee >(python logging_program.py)) 2>&1
```

If you only want to get the stderr from the session then just use `2>`:

```
(python py_prog.py | java scalaProg.Pkg;) 2> >(tee >(python logging_program.py))
```

Comment: Please explain the part where it checks for failure before redirecting it to `logging_program`

Comment: Please note that scalaProg returns stderr at all times, but we need it only when it crashes, in which case we need to send it to logging_program

Comment: @aitchnyu If you could only detect if `java scalaProg.Pkg` has already got a problem when it exits then you have to send the error output of it temporarily somewhere like on a buffer or a file. It's almost impossible if you want `python logging_program.py` to run and read its error messages after it's no longer running. If you want to have a temporary file solution it could be provided. Even when reading a named pipe, you can't continue or stop your running program unless something reads from it on the other end.

Answer (score 1):

[Tadeck's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18119167/1256452) can get you most of the way there; but one big remaining problem is the broken-pipe error killing off `py_prog.py`.

It turns out that catching broken pipes for `sys.stdout` is tricky, because sometimes they occur during shutdown when it is too late.

If `my_prog.py` is relatively clean you can wrap it with some special boilerplate.  Let's say, for illustration purposes, that it looks something like this trivial program:

```
$ cat badpipe.py
import sys

def main():
    for i in range(1000):
        print 'line', i
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        sys.exit(main())
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        sys.exit('\nInterrupted')
```

The code under the `__name__ == '__main__'` test at the end is—or has been, anyway—my usual boilerplate for my standalone python programs.  It turns out I may need to change it, based on this answer.

Anyway, if I try running this with two "bad" cases, one that exits immediately and one that reads a bit and then exits, it behaves two different ways.  First, pipe into "exit immediately":

```
$ python badpipe.py | (exit 0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "badpipe.py", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "badpipe.py", line 5, in main
    print 'line', i
IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

That's about what I expected.  But:

```
$ python badpipe.py | head -1
line 0
close failed in file object destructor:
sys.excepthook is missing
lost sys.stderr
```

Whoa!  Freaky!  :-)

It turns out I can get the freaky behavior (`lost sys.stderr`) with the `head -1` to go away by tuning up my wrapper a bit.  Instead of just `sys.exit(main())`, I need to invoke `sys.stdout.flush()` (ideally, maybe also `sys.stderr.flush()` too, but so far I have only tested this much) before calling `sys.exit`:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        ret = main()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        ret = '\nInterrupted'
    try:
        sys.stdout.flush()
    finally:
        sys.exit(ret)
```

With this in place, I can now reliably catch the outermost `IOError` and check for a broken-pipe case.  Here's the final (more or less) version, including `main` again:

```
import errno, sys

def main():
    for i in range(1000):
        print 'line', i
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ret = 0
    try:
        try:
            ret = main()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            ret = '\nInterrupted'
        finally:
            sys.stdout.flush()
    except IOError as err:
        if err.errno == errno.EPIPE:
            sys.stderr.write('caught pipe-based IO-error\n')
            ret = 123 # or whatever
        else:
            raise # some other I/O error; attempt to get a traceback
    finally:
        sys.exit(ret)
```

The `sys.stderr.write` after catching `EPIPE`, and altered `ret` value, are mainly for illustration—there's nothing special about 123.  Also I don't know if the final `raise` works right, as I have not tested it.

Running this gives:

```
$ python badpipe.py | (exit 0)
caught pipe-based IO-error
$ python badpipe.py | (head -1)
line 0
caught pipe-based IO-error
$
```

(Note: this is all in python 2.7 but 3.2 behaves similarly.)

---

This is all well and good if you can modify `py_prog.py`, but what if you can't?

In that case, I'd suggest writing a wrapper script (in whatever language, Python will work fine).  Have your wrapper script read all its stdin and copy (i.e., write) it all to stdout but check for (catch) the broken-pipe error.  If and when that occurs, change strategy: read the rest of stdin and just throw it away, so that `py_prog.py` happily believes it managed to send everything to stdout and complete.  You can even make it write it to a `subprocess.Popen` that runs your `java scalaProg.pkg` command and does all the desired special logging case for you.

You might want to write this wrapper even if you *can* modify `py_prog.py`, depending on exactly what you want to have happen.

```
python py_prog.py | python wrap_java_thing.py
```

(I'm not going to write the wrapper for you though :-) )

---

Incidentally, the `lost sys.stderr` thing is a Python bug, [issue 11380](http://bugs.python.org/issue11380).  An easy way to provoke it: `python -c 'print "foo\n"*10000' | head -1`

Answer (score 0):

Do the following: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2342841/548696

```
python py_prog.py | java scalaProg.Pkg 2>&1 >/dev/null | python logging_program.py
```

This removes anything from stdout and only stderr is passed to your Python script.

Does that work for you?

Comment: But I want `logging_program` to run only when `scalaProg` fails