# Is it possible to parse standard error without writing out to a file first?

Tags: bash, sed, awk

In a simple case, let say we have some standard error:

```
$ ls /fake/file
ls: /fake/file: No such file or directory
```

**QUESTION:** Is it possible to parse out "`/fake/file`" from the standard error without having to write it out to a file first? For example:

```
$ ls /fake/file 2> tmp.file; sed 's/.* \(.*\):.*/\1/' tmp.file
/fake/file
```

Comment: Many ways described here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342826/how-to-pipe-stderr-and-not-stdout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```bash
ls /fake/file 2>&1 | awk -F: '{print $2}'
```

Comment: The parsing is not exactly correct, but this: `ls /fake/file 2>&1` is what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

either way should fetch you the filename

```
ls /fake/file 2>&1 | awk -F: '{print $2}' | awk '{print $3}'
```

or

```
ls /fake/file 2>&1 | awk '{print $4}' | awk -F: '{print $1}'
```

or

```
ls /fake/file 2>&1 | sed 's/.* \(.*\):.*/\1/'
```

Comment: I don't think the two `awk` solutions work how you expect.