# how to capture command error message in variable for if block

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Hi below is my code for bash shell script, in this I want to capture error message for if clause, when it says either job is already running or unable to start the job to a variable, how it is possible in below script, or any other way for the below functionality

```
if initctl start $i  ; then
    echo "service $i  started by script"
else
    echo "not able to start service $i"
fi
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can for example use the syntax `msg=$(command 2>&1 1>/dev/null)` to redirect stderr to stdout after redirecting stdout to /dev/null. This way, it will just store stderr:

```
error=$(initctl start $i 2>&1 1>/dev/null)
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
   echo "service $i started by script"
else
   echo "service $i could not be started. Error: $error"
fi
```

This uses [How to pipe stderr, and not stdout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342826/how-to-pipe-stderr-and-not-stdout), so that it catches stderr from `initctl start $i` and stores in `$error` variable.

Then, `$?` contains the return code of the command, as seen in [How to check if a command succeeded?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29370/how-to-check-if-a-command-succeeded). If `0`, it succeeded; otherwise, some errors happened.

Comment: Wouldn't this solution be affected by [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/upstart/+bug/552786) ? As it is dated from 2010, I'm not sure wether it's been fixed

Comment: Interesting... I wasn't aware of that. I don't have Ubuntu here with me, so we'll have to see if it works to the OP. Reading from the bug page, it doesn't seem to have been fixed.

Comment: Well, I have a 14.04 Ubuntu VM laying around and just tested your script. It works just fine, I was able to start `cron` and it returned the correct error when `cron` was already running. It does need `sudo` to  run though, otherwise it returns an `Unknown job: xxx` error

Comment: +1 And in case OP also wants to see `stdout` if successful, he could do `out=$(initctl start $i 2>&1)` and use for both.

Answer (score 2):

Use '$?' variable
It stores any exit_code from the previous statement
See http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html for more information

```
initctl start $i
retval=$?
if [ $retval -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "service $i  started by script"
else
    echo "not able to start service $i"
fi
```