# Redirect stderr through grep -v in LSF batch job

Tags: batch-processing, io-redirection, lsf

I'm using a library that generates a whole ton of output to stderr (and there is really no way to suppress the output directly in the code; it is ROOT's Minuit2 minimizer which is known for not having a way to suppress the output). I'm running batch jobs through the LSF system, and the error output files are so big that they exceed my disk quota. Erk.

When I run locally on a shell, I do:

```
python main.py 2> >( grep -v Minuit2 2>&1 )
```

to suppress the output, as is done [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15936384/4208876)
This works great, but unfortunately I can't seem to get that or any variation of it to work when running on LSF. I think this is due to LSF not spawning the necessary subshell, but it's not clear.

I run on batch by passing LSF a submit script. The relevant line is:

```
python main.py $INPUT_FILE
```

which works great, aside from the aforementioned problem of gigantic error files.

When I try changing that line to

```
python main.py $INPUT_FILE 2> >( grep -v Minuit2 2>&1 )
```

I end up with

```
./singleSubmit.sh: line 16: syntax error near unexpected token `>'
./singleSubmit.sh: line 16: `python $MAIN $1 2> >( grep -v Minuit2 2>&1 )'
```

in the error log file.

Any idea how I could accomplish what I want, or why this is not working?

Thanks a ton!

Comment: Oh, by the way, I checked the shell that LSF runs these commands in. It is tcsh, just the same as I use locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax you're using works in bash, not in csh/tcsh.  Try changing the first line of your submission script to

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Comment: Huh. I thought I tried that. Thank you so much for the help!! :)

Comment: Out of curiosity, why does `python main.py $INPUT_FILE 2> >( grep -v Minuit2 2>&1 )` work in interactive tcsh? Shouldn't I get the same error?

Comment: That's a good question, because I don't think it should.  I'm running tcsh interactively and can't get it to work: the error message I get is "Missing name for redirect"

Comment: Yeah, turns out I was just being silly - I was actually running interactively in zsh. I get the same result as you for tcsh. Cheers!