# Why does /bin/sh behave differently to /bin/bash even if one points to the other?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

While I was playing around in my shell investigating the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26707034/redirect-stderr-through-grep-v-in-lsf-batch-job), I noticed that, even though `/bin/sh` was pointing to `/bin/bash` on my system, the two commands behave differently.  First of all, the output of

```
ls -lh /bin/sh
```

is:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Apr 22  2013 /bin/sh -> bash*
```

However, invoking the following command through `/bin/sh`:

```
/bin/sh -c "script.sh 2> >( grep -v FILTER 2>&1 )"
```

returns this error:

```
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token '>'
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: 'script.sh 2> >( grep -v FILTER 2>&1 )'
```

While running the same command through `/bin/bash`:

```
/bin/bash -c "script.sh 2> >( grep -v FILTER 2>&1 )"
```

executes successfully, here is the output:

```
This should be on stderr
```

For reference, here is the contents of `script.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "FILTER: This should be filtered out" 1>&2
echo "This should be on stderr" 1>&2
echo "FILTER: This should be filtered out" 1>&2
```

Why do the two invocations behave differently?

Comment: Oftentimes the same person will react differently depending on how you address them.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20195377/834309

Answer (score 81, accepted):

`bash` looks at the value of `$argv[0]` (bash is implemented in C) to determine how it was invoked.

Its behavior when invoked as `sh` is documented [in the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html):

> If Bash is invoked with the name `sh`, it tries to mimic the startup
>   behavior of historical versions of `sh` as closely as possible, while
>   conforming to the POSIX standard as well.
>
> When invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a non-interactive
>   shell with the `-login` option, it first attempts to read and execute
>   commands from `/etc/profile` and `~/.profile`, in that order. The
>   `--noprofile` option may be used to inhibit this behavior. When invoked as an interactive shell with the name `sh`, Bash looks for the variable
>   `ENV`, expands its value if it is defined, and uses the expanded value
>   as the name of a file to read and execute. Since a shell invoked as `sh`
>   does not attempt to read and execute commands from any other startup
>   files, the `--rcfile` option has no effect. A non-interactive shell
>   invoked with the name `sh` does not attempt to read any other startup
>   files.
>
> When invoked as `sh`, Bash enters POSIX mode after the startup files are
>   read

There's a long list (currently 46 items) of things that change when `bash` is in POSIX mode, [documented here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-POSIX-Mode.html).

(POSIX mode is probably useful mostly as a way to test scripts for portability to non-`bash` shells.)

Incidentally, programs that change their behavior depending on the name under which they were invoked are fairly common. Some versions of `grep`, `fgrep`, and `egrep` are implemented as a single executable (though GNU `grep` doesn't do this). `view` is typically a symbolic link to `vi` or `vim`; invoking it as `view` causes to open in read-only mode. The [Busybox](http://www.busybox.net/) system includes a number of individual commands that are all symlinks to the master `busybox` executable.

Comment: Thank you!  That's really great info, I'd never noticed that in the manual before.

Comment: This is also how the busybox tools determine what to do. Internally looking at $argv[0] is a nifty way to make one binary behave as several individual tools.

Comment: @pierce.jason: In some implementations, `grep`, `fgrep`, and `egrep` work this way. (I just found out that GNU grep doesn't do this; they're three separate executables.) Similarly, `view` is typically the same executable as `vi` or `vim`; invoking it as `view` is equivalent to using the `-R` (readonly) option.

Comment: `view is typically a symbolic link to vi or vim` and in many systems, vi is actually vim running in vi-compatible mode.

Answer (score 20):

Invoking bash as `sh` causes it to enter *posix mode* after reading the startup files it would normally read (as opposed to the startup files a POSIX sh would read.) Bash has many different invocation modes. You can find out about these modes from the `INVOCATION` section of the manual. Here is some detail about the POSIX mode.

### POSIX mode

This mode means bash will try, in various degrees, to conform to POSIX expectations. As explained [here](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/POSIX), bash has a few different invocations for this mode, with slightly different implications:

1. `sh`: Bash enters POSIX mode after reading startup files.
2. `bash --posix`: Bash enters POSIX mode *before* reading startup files.
3. `set -o posix`: Bash switches to POSIX mode.
4. `POSIXLY_CORRECT`: If this variable is in the environment when bash starts, the shell enters posix mode *before* reading the startup files, like `bash --posix`. If it is set while bash is running, like `set -o posix`.

Answer (score 16):

From the [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Invoked-with-name-sh):

> If Bash is invoked with the name sh, it tries to mimic the startup behavior of historical versions of sh as closely as possible, while conforming to the POSIX standard as well.

Answer (score 11):

Because the `bash` binary checks how it was invoked (via `argv[0]`) and enters a compatibility mode if it's being run as `sh`.