# sort -t $'\t' equivalent compatible with POSIX sh?

Tags: unix, sh

I am trying use a for loop for multiple files in my directory with a pipe command,but it does not seem to work. When am running the same command on a single file it seems to work. Where am I getting it wrong?

```
for x in *summary-FDR0.05 ; do sort -t $'\t' -k8,8rn $x | head -n 50000 | sortBed -i > sorted_top_50k_$x.bed; done
```

All my files end with `summary-FDR0.05`. When I run

```
sort -t $'\t' -k8,8rn sample13-summary-FDR0.05 | head -n 50000 | sortBed -i > sorted_top_50k_S_13_O1_122*K27ac.bed
```

This seems to work well. May I know where I am getting it worng

Error:

```
sort: multi-character tab `$\\t'
```

Thanks

Comment: Looks *vaguely* like you are using `sh` instead of `bash` when you get the error message.

Comment: but how do I get this rectified, does not posix compatibility allow to run `sh` under `bash`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26717870/why-does-bin-sh-behave-differently-to-bin-bash-even-if-one-points-to-the-other

Comment: You can easily run `sh` code in Bash but you appear to want to do the opposite. Either write portable code (no `$'\t'` then, for example) which works in any POSIX shell; or write Bash code, and run it in Bash only.

Comment: I am unable to solve it. any leads?

Comment: How are you running the script? Does it have a shebang line? Does it work if you run it with `bash filename`?

Comment: Yes it does have for `#!/bin/sh` . this fails. I also did `#!/bin/bash`. But fails again. I do not want to run it will file name. All the files are in a directory so I want to loop all the files in the directory and while each file is picked up , I want to execute the sorting in tab delimited file with column 8 and then take top 50k rows in each file and since it is bed12 format file want to use sortBed command and output finally. So the piping was done to do all at one go.

Comment: It certainly should not fail with `#!/bin/bash`. Can you show reproduction steps for that failure?

Comment: BTW, there are other bugs in here which http://shellcheck.net/ will identify for you automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For POSIX compatibility, replace `$'\t'` with `"$(printf "\t")"`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works. I was not able to understand what should be the POSIX compatibility in this case. Thanks a lot

Comment: If this solved your problem, please click the hollow tick mark so it turns green. That way, this question will no longer come up as unresolved. Thanks.