# How to modify a config parameter value with slash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, sh

I am trying to modify a config file `demo.cfg` from a `.sh` file. I can modify it using `sed`, but the problem is when the value contains slash character.

For that I am using this code:

```
read -r -p "(Default PATH: /my/default/path/): " response
    case $response in
        (*[![:blank:]]*) sed -i '/key_one/s/= ''.*/= '$response'/' demo.cfg; echo 'OK';;
        (*) echo 'Using default path'
    esac
```

Here the error when the variable `$response` has slash:

`sed: -e expression #1, char 20: unknown option to "s"`

Could I scape this variable to use with sed function?

Here `demo.cfg` file

```
[params]
key_one = 1
key_two = 9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing `response` like this

```
${response//\//\\/}
```

This replaces all `/` with `\/`. Example:

```
$ response=/my/path/to/target
$ echo ${response//\//\\/}
\/my\/path\/to\/target
```

There is also an issue with your case statement. Your bash script should look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -r -p "(Default PATH: /my/default/path/): " response
    case $response in
        *[![:blank:]]*) sed -i "/key_one/s/= .*/= ${response//\//\\/}/" demo.cfg
                echo 'OK'
                ;;
        *) echo 'Using default path'
                ;;
        esac
```

Comment: I am using this: `echo $response; sed -i '/key_one/s/= ''.*/= 'echo ${response//\//\\/}'/' demo.cfg;` but it fails: `Bad substitution`

Comment: The `echo` was only meant to demonstrate the behavior in bash. You do not need the `echo` inside the script. Just `${response//\//\\/}` will suffice.

Comment: @oscarvady There is also an issue with your `case` statement. I updated your script.

Comment: It fails again at sed line: `Bad substitution` :(

Comment: @oscarvady Did you copy/paste my updated script? Which version of bash are you using? It works in my bash 4.3.42.

Comment: Yes, it works now. I was using `#!/bin/sh` instead of `#!/bin/bash`. Could I execute this script as `sh`? Thanks again

Comment: @oscarvady `sh` normally behaves differently than `bash`, even if `/bin/sh` points to `bash`. See this thread for more info on this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26717870/why-does-bin-sh-behave-differently-to-bin-bash-even-if-one-points-to-the-other

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

- Use a different separator for substitution, e.g. `#` or `_`:

  ```
  sed 's#/foo/bar/#/spam/egg#' file.txt
  ```

  Here use something that is not present in the pattern for clarity..
- Or escape the actual `/`:

  ```
  sed 's/\/foo\/bar\//\/spam\/egg/' file.txt
  ```

  this is not cleanly readable, hence not recommended.

Comment: Why second option is not recommended? I can't modify the separator.

Comment: How could escape in my example the variable `$response`? Thanks again

Comment: @heemayl Any character that you choose for the delimiter could occur in the path, so escaping it is really the only choice.

Comment: @chepner Correct but if that character is not present in the Regex pattern then its fine i think..

Comment: You don't know the regex pattern ahead of time; it is constructed dynamically from the user's input.

Answer (score 0):

To escape your chosen delimiter, use parameter expansion:

```
$ response=/foo/bar
$ response=${response//\//\\\/}
$ echo "$response"
```