# Git Grep => Why doesn't `git grep -h` work with Unix pipes?

Tags: git, grep

I was trying to run this command (on a Mac)...

```
$ git grep -h | grep dir
```

Instead of printing the lines containing `dir`, it prints all the text for `git grep -h`, and effectively ignores `| grep dir`.

I also tried this...

```
$ git grep -h > foo.txt
```

...which prints it prints all the text for `git grep -h`, and creates an empty text file.

What's going on here?

Comment: You are running an incomplete command, so `git grep` is writing its help message to standard error, rather than writing actual output to standard output.

Comment: `git grep -h` without a pipe does the same as with a pipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git grep` expects a pattern to search. Because you didn't provide it, it displays the help on `stderr` (while you pipe or redirect the `stdout`).

The command you need to run to accomplish your goal is:

```
$ git grep -h dir
```

Comment: thanks.  I couldn't get `git grep -h dir` to work, but you were correct about stderr.  I search for stderr answers, found [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342826/how-to-pipe-stderr-and-not-stdout), and solved the problem with `git grep -h 2>&1 >/dev/null | grep 'dir'`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to put your regex after the command like so: `git grep -h dir`

Then you can pipe it to an output file or do anything else with that data.