# Redirecting java and javac output

Tags: java, redirect, pipe, output, javac

I'm trying to write an installation (bash) script, in which I need to check if user has the java 1.8 installed.

The obvious way to do that is to call

```
javac -version | grep 1.8
```

, but for some strange reason javac (and java) -version output can't be redirected - neither by |, > or >> - in the first case, the second program doesn't get any input, in second and third, the output file is empty after executing the command.
I've tried to check it on three different machines, the result was the same on each of them.

What is the cause of that?
Is there any other way I can check the java version?

Comment: You know what stdout and stderr is?  (also you might want to consider writing a small Java 1.3 program which tests the facilities provided by the JVM directly using reflection)

Comment: Also, what will you do when java 1.9 comes out?

Comment: I don't really care about the 1.9 version, since the software won't be in use then.
And 'small Java 1.3' program won't work if there's no java at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that the output is sent to `STDERR`. Try this:

```
javac -version 2>&1
```

This will redirect the output of `STDERR` to `STDOUT`. Now you should be able to pipe the command.

If you just want to redirect it to a file, just replace `&1` by the filename, so:

```
javac -version 2>out
```

Comment: `2>&1` does not "redirect to stdout instead of stderr". What is does is redirect stderr to stdout. That's not the same thing ;)

Comment: @Vivin Paliath - you're absolutely correct: `2>&1` redirects both stdout and stderr "to the same place".  It's an excellent solution to this problem.  ALSO: I didn't know until very recently that this syntax *ALSO* works in a Windows/DOS .bat file.

Comment: @fge Oops you're absolutely right. That's what I meant to say :)

Comment: Thanks. And if one wants to redirect it to pipe, to use it in grep/sed/less/anything, there is a syntax of

command 2>&1 >/dev/null | grep 'sth'

(from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342826/how-to-pipe-stderr-and-not-stdout)

Answer (score 0):

you can simply check your java versionby using this tool:
http://www.java.com/en/download/installed.jsp