# How can I use logger with tee in CentOS 6.X

Tags: linux, tee

I have tried to use these commands to test my shell script:

```
logger "hello i am fun" | tee -a test
```

But the test file still empty. I have also tried to use echo

```
echo "hello i am fun" |tee -a test >logger
```

It also failed  writing to test file. how can I use the logger with tee -a?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Can you provide what does the test file contain?

Answer (score 0):

`logger` has an `-s` flag:

> -s       Output the message to standard error as well as to the system
>                 log.

*Source: [LOGGER(1) Man Pages](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/logger.1.html)*

You can use the `-s` to log the message to standard error.
Then redirect stderr to stdout and then stdout to `/dev/null`.
Pipe the whole thing into `tee`, and you'll end up with your message in your syslog as well as the path you specified in `tee`.

Example:

```
joeyoung$ logger -s -p local0.notice -t TEST "test message" 2>&1 >/dev/null |  tee -a /tmp/teetemp.log
Oct  3 11:11:54 localhost TEST[4231] <Notice>: test message
joeyoung$ tail -n1 /var/log/messages
Oct  3 11:11:54 localhost TEST[4231]: test message
joeyoung$ cat /tmp/teetemp.log
Oct  3 11:11:54 localhost TEST[4231] <Notice>: test message
```

For proper attribution, some inspiration taken from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2342841/2744166