# Grep python output stream (tried print and stdout)

Tags: python, grep, stdout

This answer says it's as simple as:

[pipe python logging stdout stream output to grep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33438595/pipe-python-logging-stdout-stream-output-to-grep)

`python main.py 2>&1 | grep INFO`

I have the following file, which I've tried with `print()` and `sys.stdout.write()`.

```
import sys
from time import sleep

while True:
    sleep(1)
    sys.stdout.write("this is a thing")
    # Also tried print()
```

I'm trying to collect `"thing"` with:

`python output.py 2>&1 | grep "thing"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `newline` and better to `flush` the `stdout`.

```
import sys
from time import sleep

while True:
    sys.stdout.write("this is a thing\n")
    sys.stdout.flush()
    sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while True:
    sleep(1)
    print("this is a thing", flush=True)
```

Will work as well, no need to hustle with stdout directly.

By default `print` uses buffer for output, just by flushing it every call you'll have semi-realtime streaming.

Answer (score 0):

as an addition: if the output would have gone to stderr, whats not the case here, you would still see it in the terminal, because the pipe | only redirects stdout if you don't specify otherwise
the rest goes unfiltered to the terminal