# How to print everything that is printed and can be seen on terminal

Tags: bash, stdout, stderr

I want to print all the output from GROMACS 5.1.2.

I know how to use `>` and `<` for std in and out, also tried `2>&1` to print error and output together, tried separately too, it will still not print everything, especially some useful hints in the end when it tells me what was the problem and I need that information.

I think this will not be saved because it is coming from a different code, the main program executes a sub program, and that crashes, and I get the report only on screen. I will have in the output that something went wrong, and what that something is, but on the screen I have much more information.

If anyone has any idea how I could do that, I would really appreciate it.

Also I'm not complete noob, but if you can be explicit in your explanation, that is greatly appreciated.

For example if you would like to try `gmx pdb2gmx` command with the `3mlj.pdb` from RCBS Protein Database, on screen I will be reading:

> ```
> Fatal error:
> Residue 'CU' not found in residue topology database
> ```

But in the standard output I will only read:

> ```
> This chain does not appear to contain a recognized chain molecule.
> ```

For me that CU is really important information, and this is just an example.

I'm sharing my operating system here:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

Also tried on this with the exact same result:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.10
Release:    15.10
Codename:   wily
```

My bash script that I want to run for batch files:

```
#$ -S /bin/bash
for infile in *.pdb
do
    gmx pdb2gmx -f $infile -o ${infile/pdb/gro} -water spce -ff oplsaa \
        -p ${infile/pdb/top} -i ${infile/pdb/itp} 2>&1 > ${infile/pdb/err}
done
```

Comment: `command 2>&1` doesn't work for you? Which os? please add exact example of your command line

Comment: I've included my ubuntu version in my description and my bash script.

Comment: Is there any more output with the "Fatal error" message (file, line number, etc.)?

Comment: No file or line number, it's just text, like comments, or warnings that are not fatal, and will let the program continue.

Comment: Thank you everyone, I was trying to upvote but I need to earn reputation, but it said, that once I will have enough it will be done automatically, I don't have to come back and do it again (but I will do it anyways).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must do I/O redirections in the correct order (left to right).

You have:

```
gmx pdb2gmx …  -i ${infile/pdb/itp} 2>&1 > ${infile/pdb/err}
```

This sends standard error to where standard output is currently going (the terminal), and then sends standard output (but not standard error) to a file.

You need:

```
gmx pdb2gmx …  -i ${infile/pdb/itp} > ${infile/pdb/err} 2>&1
```

This sends standard output to a file, and then sends standard error to the same place.  Note that in both systems, there are still two separate file descriptors (`1` or standard output, and `2` or standard error) in use; the only question is which file the file descriptor is connected to.

If you're piping data, the pipe is set up before other I/O redirections are dealt with, but otherwise, I/O redirections per command are processed left-to-right.

See also [How to pipe stderr and not stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342826/how-to-pipe-stderr-and-not-stdout/2342841#2342841), and Bash [I/O Redirections](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirections).

Comment: Thank you very much, this actually solved the problem. I thought I have to tell the computer first, that I want both to go to the same place, and than tell it where that is, but now I understand. (And I thought I know how to use it)
Thanks again