# Sed error "command a expects \ followed by text"

Tags: bash, sed, openscad

Here is my script:

```
openscad $1 -D generate=1 -o $1.csg 2>&1 >/dev/null |
sed 's/ECHO: \"\[LC\] //' |
sed 's/"$//' |
sed '$a;' >./2d_$1
```

That output:

```
sed: 1: "$a;": command a expects \ followed by text
```

Comment: You're redirecting your output to `/dev/null`, how is `sed` going to get anything at all? What is `sed '$a;'` supposed to do?

Comment: @miken32: The errors from `openscad` go to `sed`; the standard output from `sed` goes to `/dev/null`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler doesn't `2>&1 >/dev/null` mean stderr goes to stdout, which goes to null?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Add a line that contains a semicolon at the end of the output?  Which variant of `sed` are you using?  GNU `sed` allows barbaric constructions like the one you're trying to use — if I've guessed correctly — but standard versions of `sed` (those conforming to the POSIX standard) require `sed -e '$a\'` and then the semicolon in either a second `-e` argument or after a newline in the single quoted string (which can't be shown in comment on SO).

Comment: @miken32: No — see [How to pipe stderr and not stdout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342826/how-to-pipe-stderr-and-not-stdout/2342841#2342841)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler that's counterintuitive! Thanks for the tip.

Comment: I didn't even know there were different sed versions, I'm actually using the Mac OSX one, the same as FreeBSD according to my Internet searches.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your version of `sed` is not GNU `sed` which allows what you use.  You need to write:

```
openscad $1 -D generate=1 -o $1.csg 2>&1 >/dev/null |
sed 's/ECHO: \"\[LC\] //' |
sed 's/"$//' |
sed '$a\
;' >./2d_$1
```

Also, three copies of `sed` is a little excessive (to be polite); one suffices:

```
openscad $1 -D generate=1 -o $1.csg 2>&1 >/dev/null |
sed -e 's/ECHO: \"\[LC\] //' \
    -e 's/"$//' \
    -e '$a\' \
    -e ';' >./2d_$1
```

or:

```
openscad $1 -D generate=1 -o $1.csg 2>&1 >/dev/null |
sed -e 's/ECHO: \"\[LC\] //' -e 's/"$//' -e '$a\' -e ';' >./2d_$1
```

Comment: if you are on mac and you want to use gnu sed (you really do). you can install it with `brew install gnu-sed` and run gsed

Comment: For the record, the `i` and `c` commands in `sed` behave similarly. If you require a portable solution, maybe don't write it in `sed`. Awk and Perl let you write simila scripts, albeit with different syntax. Some simple `sed` scripts can be rewritten in Perl with very minor changes; maybe also check out the tool `s2p`.

Answer (score 1):

On MacOS, the following works when trying to use command 'a'

```
sed '/REGEX/a \
    HELLO_WORLD \
    HOW_ARE_YOU \
' <filePath>
```

Comment: It does, but why?