# Extract part of string in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, macos, macos-sierra

When I import my GPG keys, I get a response back:

```
gpg: key LOL12345: public key "John Doe (Developer) <john@doe.com>" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
```

I would very much like to extract the key's ID `LOL12345`.

The command I run that returns the output is as follows:

```
gpg --import "public.key"
```

Comment: probably the `gpg` command has some option to list only keys... skimmed through man page and saw options like `--list-keys`, `-k` etc.. see if that helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use grep:

```
yourCommand | grep -Po -m 1 'gpg: key \K\w+'
```

`-P` use perl regex style.
`-o` print only the matched part.
`-m 1` exit after the first match. This will ensure, that the key is not printed multiple times.
`\K` once matched, forget the matched part left of `\K`.
`\w+` Match as many alphanumeric characters as possible.

Comment: When executing the `gpg` command it's like the output is never "caught" by `|` and the hereafter method.

It just outputs exactly the same as before as if it's ignoring everything after the `|`.

Comment: Does gpg print to stderr? If so, redirect the output. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2342841/6770384).

Comment: It did! Your link helped me out. But I liked @heemayl method with `awk` a bit better, so my answer was a mix of both  your answers :D

Answer (score 1):

With `awk`:

```
gpg --import "public.key" | awk -F '[ :]' 'NR==1 {print $4; exit}'
```

- `-F '[ :]'` sets the field delimiter as space or `:`
- `NR==1` matches the first line, `{print $4; exit}` prints the 4th field (desired field), and then `exit`s

If `gpg` is output-ing to STDERR:

```
gpg --import "public.key" |& awk -F '[ :]' 'NR==1 {print $4; exit}'
```

For an older `bash`:

```
gpg --import "public.key" 2>&1 | awk -F '[ :]' 'NR==1 {print $4; exit}'
```

**Example:**

```
% cat file.txt
gpg: key LOL12345: public key "John Doe (Developer) <john@doe.com>" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
gpg: key LOL12345: secret key imported
gpg: key LOL12345: "John Doe (Developer) <john@doe.com>" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1
gpg:       secret keys read: 1
gpg:   secret keys imported: 1

% awk -F '[ :]' 'NR==1 {print $4; exit}' file.txt
LOL12345
```

Comment: When executing the `gpg` command it's like the output is never "caught" by `|` and the hereafter method.

It just outputs exactly the same as before as if it's ignoring everything after the `|`.

Comment: @MortenRugaard Probably because `gpg` is sending the output to STDERR, do: `gpg --import "public.key" |& awk -F '[ :]' 'NR==1 {print $4; exit}'`

Comment: Oh okay, so in you're example you're using `awk` with a file. But how do I write a temp. file with the output if it's ignoring everything after `|`?

Comment: Now I'm getting `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `&'`

Comment: @MortenRugaard Check my edits. Do: `gpg --import "public.key" 2>&1 | awk -F '[ :]' 'NR==1 {print $4; exit}'`

Comment: @Socowi Had the answer to grab the output: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40220672/extract-part-of-string-in-bash#comment67705024_40220763

But I liked your way with using `awk` better, the answer was a mix of both your answers.