# Linux Bash script redirect only if the log contains ERROR

Tags: linux, bash, hive

I'm new to Linux Bash script and learning. I'm just wondering is it possible to redirect stderr to a file only if the stderr contains ERROR.

I am executing Hadoop Hive commands, which I put it in a Bash script file to  schedule the process. The hive command generates a lot of logs, and I don't want to redirect the logs to a file every time, But if the log contains Errors, then I want to redirect the log to a file and want to mail the error file to someone.

Please let me know how to achieve this. Thanks in advance..

Regards,
Jeeva

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pipe stderr, and not stdout?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342826/how-to-pipe-stderr-and-not-stdout)

Comment: @AlexL. How does that answer the question? He wants the redirection to be conditional on the content.

Comment: that question describes how to pipe stderr specifically through grep..  so Jee should grep for `ERROR`

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, if an error occurs, you want to preserve the
entire error log in a file (including lines that might not match your error-detection pattern.).  I don't think there's any way to achieve what you 
want purely through I/O redirection.

Instead, you can unconditionally redirect stderr to its own file.  Then,
as a post-processing step, you can grep through that file to see if
ERROR shows up, and depending on the outcome, either mail the file
to someone, or delete it.

Comment: I think your interpretation makes sense. Python/ruby could help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the stderr file descriptor which is 2

For example:

```
rm this-file-does-not-exist.txt 
>>>> rm: cannot remove ‘asdfasf.js’: No such file or directory
# to redirect that error to a file you do this
rm this-file-does-not-exist.txt 2>/tmp/logError.txt
cat /tmp/logError.txt
>>>> rm: cannot remove ‘asdfasf.js’: No such file or directory
# if you want to check if the output contains `ERROR` do this
badcommand | grep "ERROR" 1>/tmp/logError.txt # if greping for "ERROR" was successfull redirect stdout to /tmp/logError.txt
# the 1 is a file descriptor for stdout
```

[How to use linux mail command](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-write-command-to-send-receive-mail/)

Comment: How does this make the redirection dependent on whether the output contains `ERROR`?