# Extract single line from command output in terminal

Tags: regex, bash, grep, perf

I would like to extract the line containing 'seconds time elapsed' output from perf stat output for some logging script that I am working on.

I do not want to write the output to a file and then search the file. I would like to do it using 'grep' or something similar.

Here is what I have tried:

```
perf stat -r 10 echo "Sample_String" | grep -eE "seconds time elapsed"
```

For which I get

```
    grep: seconds time elapsed: No such file or directory
    echo: Broken pipe
    echo: Broken pipe
    echo: Broken pipe 
    echo: Broken pipe
    echo: Broken pipe
    echo: Broken pipe
    echo: Broken pipe
    echo: Broken pipe
    echo: Broken pipe

    Performance counter stats for 'echo Sample_String' (10 runs):

      0.254533      task-clock (msec)         #    0.556 CPUs utilized            ( +-  0.98% )
             0      context-switches          #    0.000 K/sec                  
             0      cpu-migrations            #    0.000 K/sec                  
            56      page-faults               #    0.220 M/sec                    ( +-  0.53% )
       <not supported>      cycles                   
       <not supported>      stalled-cycles-frontend  
       <not supported>      stalled-cycles-backend   
       <not supported>      instructions             
       <not supported>      branches                 
       <not supported>      branch-misses            

   0.000457686 seconds time elapsed                                          ( +-  1.08% )
```

And I tried this

```
perf stat -r 10 echo "Sample_String" > grep -eE "seconds time elapsed"
```

For which I got

```
 Performance counter stats for 'echo Sample_String -eE seconds time elapsed' (10 runs):

      0.262585      task-clock (msec)         #    0.576 CPUs utilized            ( +-  1.11% )
             0      context-switches          #    0.000 K/sec                  
             0      cpu-migrations            #    0.000 K/sec                  
            56      page-faults               #    0.214 M/sec                    ( +-  0.36% )
    <not supported>      cycles                   
    <not supported>      stalled-cycles-frontend  
    <not supported>      stalled-cycles-backend   
    <not supported>      instructions             
    <not supported>      branches                 
    <not supported>      branch-misses            

   0.000456035 seconds time elapsed                                          ( +-  1.05% )
```

I am new to these tools like grep, awk and sed. I hope someone can help me out. I also do not want to write the output to a file and then search the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the output you want is sent to `stderr` instead of the standard output.

You can see this by redirecting stderr to /dev/null, and you'll see that the only result left is the one from the "echo" command.

```
~/ perf stat -r 10 echo "Sample_String" 2>/dev/null
Sample_String
Sample_String
Sample_String
Sample_String
Sample_String
Sample_String
Sample_String
Sample_String
Sample_String
Sample_String
```

In order to do what you want, you will have to redirect `perf`'s stderr to the standard output, and hide the standard output. This way, `perf`'s output will be sent to the `grep` command.

```
~/ perf stat -r 10 echo "Sample_String" 2>&1 >/dev/null | grep 'seconds time elapsed'       
       0,013137361 seconds time elapsed                                          ( +- 96,08% )
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. What does '2>&1' do and what does it mean?

Comment: It redirects stderr to stdout. See this post for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2342841/2679935

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your desired output is going to `stderr`. Try:

```
perf stat -r 10 echo "Sample_String" 2>&1 | grep "seconds time elapsed"
```

Comment: Yours doesn't work. I am getting this error: "grep: seconds time elapsed: No such file or directory"

Comment: Now it works. Thanks! What does 2>&1 do and what is it called?

Comment: @SriHariVignesh Unix standard file descriptors: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor
0 - stdin
1 - stdout
2 - stderr

`2>$1` - redirects stderr to stdout which is piped to `grep`

Answer (score 1):

This could work the way you intend:

```
grep -e "seconds time elapsed" <<< "$(perf stat -r 10 echo "Sample_String" 2>&1 >/dev/null)"
```

Output:

```
0.000544399 seconds time elapsed                                          ( +-  2.05% )
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. what is the '<<<' operator called?

Comment: It is called a "Here String". See: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Strings