# Prefix for command output

Tags: bash, command-line, stdout, stderr

From [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/623112/prefix-to-each-output-of-a-command-on-runtime)  I learned how to add a prefix to each output of a command:

```
command | sed "s/^/[prefix] /"
```

But this only adds the prefix for each line from `stdout`.
I successfully used the following to add the prefix also to `stderr` output.

```
command 2>&1 | sed "s/^/[prefix] /"
```

But this sends the result to `stdout` only.

How can I prefix any output of `command` while pushing the lines to the previous output (preserving both stdout and stderr)?

Comment: Why not redirect in like manner? `command 2>&1 | sed "s/^/[prefix] /" 1>&2` ??  You redirect `stderr` to `stdout`, you pipe to `sed`, and then if you want to issue that output on `stderr`, you redirect `stdout` to `stderr`. Each pipe just directs the `stdout` of the first process to the `stdin` of the next. If you want your final output on `stderr`, then you must redirect the final `stdout` to `stderr`.

Comment: But then I send Everything to stderr. I want to preserve stdout and stderr

Comment: If you want the info out on `stdout`, then you have to do nothing, that is the default output stream. It's only if you need to change it that you redirect.

Answer (score 4):

As a combination of iBug's answer and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9217228/7365127) and [especially this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15936384/7365127) answer, I came up with a one-liner that uses temporary file descriptors:

```
command 1> >(sed "s/^/[prefix]/") 2> >(sed "s/^/[prefix]/" >&2)
```

Or as a function:

```
function prefix_cmd {
    local PREF="${1//\//\\/}" # replace / with \/
    shift
    local CMD=("$@")
    ${CMD[@]} 1> >(sed "s/^/${PREF}/") 2> >(sed "s/^/${PREF}/" 1>&2)
}
prefix_cmd "prefix" command
```

Comment: Note that when you use new variables in a function, it's usually a good idea to make them `local`. That way, you won't clobber pre-existing variables `$PREF` and `$CMD`, in case you're using those names elsewhere in your script.

Answer (score 1):

You can only pipe stdout using the shell pipe syntax. You need two pipes if you want to process stdout and stderr separately. A named pipe may work here.

Here's a sample script that demonstrates the solution

```
#!/bin/bash

PREF="$1"
shift

NPOUT=pipe.out
NPERR=pipe.err
mkfifo $NPOUT $NPERR

# Make two background sed processes
sed "s/^/$PREF/" <$NPOUT &
sed "s/^/$PREF/" <$NPERR >&2 &

# Run the program
"$@" >$NPOUT 2>$NPERR
rm $NPOUT $NPERR
```

Usage:

```
./foo.sh "[prefix] " command -options
```

It will feed `command` with its stdin and send `command`'s stdout and stderr to its stdout and stderr separately.

Note I didn't suppress `sed`'s stderr, which may interfere with the output. You can do so like this:

```
sed "s/^/$PREF/" <$NPOUT 2>/dev/null &
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: How to avoid `[1] 1178
[2] 1179` ... `[1]-  Done                    sed "s/^/$PREF/" < $NPOUT
[2]+  Done                    sed "s/^/$PREF/" < $NPERR 1>&2` ?

Comment: This solution is nice because apart from the `$CMD` array, it's POSIX compliant (and therefore portable). Any reason you need to use `$CMD` this way? Would `$@` alone be sufficient?

Comment: @RoVo Those shouldn't pop up if you run it in a script. It's generated by Bash and only appears in interactive mode.