# Is this redirecting stderr to stdout? 2>&1

Tags: ubuntu, logging, stdout, stdin, stderr

I have seen this command

> (echo "hello world" >> /var/log/hello.txt") 2>&1

Usually if I wanted to log out errors in case a command failed e.g the `echo` command for example, I'd do:

```
echo "hello world" 2>/var/log/hello-error.log
```

And if I wanted to log out both stdout and stderror, I'd do:

```
echo "hello world" &>/var/log/hello-out-and-error.log
```

And if I didn't care where these logs went, I'd log them to /dev/null for example

```
echo "hello world" 2>/dev/null
```

However, recently, I've come accross this notation and not sure what it means:

(echo "hello world" >> /var/log/hello.txt") 2>&1

What does the notation

> 2>&1

mean?

*Are we grabbing `stderror` and logging it out to `stdout`? Even saying it doesn't seem to make sense*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pipe stderr, and not stdout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342826/how-to-pipe-stderr-and-not-stdout)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In the shell, what does " 2>&1 " mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818255/in-the-shell-what-does-21-mean)