# How to pass terminal errors into Python script?

Tags: python

How to Pass a Terminal error into the Python program whenever the error is triggered in the terminal?

**Example:**

Consider I'm running a java program and I get some error like this

```sh
file.java:2: error: ',', ')', or '[' expected
    public static void main(String args...) {
                                       ^
1 error
```

Another example by entering the wrong bash command

```sh
ls: option '--a' is ambiguous; possibilities: '--all' '--almost-all' '--author'
Try 'ls --help' for more information.
```

I need to pass this error to a python program and run the program whenever the terminal shows the error like this.

How can I pass the error?

Comment: What you mean by "pass this error". There can be long error. Do you want to pass any specific error keyword to your script?

Comment: @py_saad I want to pass the entire error as a string to the constructor.

Comment: Do you want to pipe `|` the error into a Python script? In this case, [this may help](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2342826/1639625)