# Echo bash command to stdout and a log file?

Tags: bash

I'd like to know if there's a way in bash have the **current command statement** printed to both stdout and a log file, in addition to the command's output. For example:

`runme.sh:`

```sh
# do some setup, e.g. create script.log
echo "Fully logged command"
```

Would write the following to stdout **and** to `script.log`:

```sh
+ echo 'Fully logged command'
Fully logged command
```

---

For example, if I use these lines early in the script:

```
set -x
exec > >(tee -ai script.log)
```

This produces the command output from `set -x` in stdout but not in the log file.

Comment: @sunknudsen that question doesn't discuss echoing the commands themselves to logs.

Comment: Again, sorry for misinterpreting your question. Comment deleted.

Answer (score 1):

I have done a bit of testing, and as it appears, `set -x` prints its messages to stderr. This, however, means that you need to redirect stderr to stdout and pipe stdout to tee.

So if you are doing this:

```
set -x
exec 2>&1 > >(tee -ai output.log)
```

... you are neatly getting everything that Bash executes in your log file as well, together with any output produced by any commands that you are executing.

But beware: Any formatting that may be applied by your programs are lost.

As a side note, [as has been explained in some answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342826/how-to-pipe-stderr-and-not-stdout), any pipes are created before any redirections take effect. So when you are redirecting stderr to a piped stdout, that is also going to wind up in said pipe.