# Pipe output to stdout and file, but strip off color codes for file writes

Tags: bash, stdout, stderr, tee

I have a command that is constantly running and prints a log in different colors to the terminal. And I'd like to redirect that commands output to a file, but also keep in the terminal.

So far this can simply be done with `tee` as in:

```
echo -e "\033[0;31mHello world\033[0m" 2>&1 | tee ./output.txt
```

But here comes the tricky part:

I don't want the color codes to appear in the file. And since my command runs over multiple hours at a time it can't be removed after the command has been executed, but it has to be removed while the command is still running.

If I run:

```
echo -e "\033[0;31mHello world\033[0m" 2>&1 | tee ./output.txt | sed -r "s/\x1B\[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[mGK]//g"
```

then it removes the color for the terminal prints, but the color codes are still printed to the output file, so I kind of need to reverse this.

Any ideas how this could be done?

Comment: Why don't you put the `sed` command before the `tee` command?

Comment: Because I would lose the colors entirely. As I said, I still want the colors for the prints on the terminal, I just want to remove them for the file writes.

Comment: Did you see this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/2342841/3508655

Comment: @Forivin Aah alright, sorry. For the record, what is the true command you are using? Doesn't it have an option to redirect logs to a file?

Comment: I'd just do something like: `echo -e "\033[0;31mHello world\033[0m" | tee /dev/tty | sed -r "s/\x1B\[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[mGK]//g" >output.txt`

Comment: Or use `tee >(sed  's/fix/up/g' > output.txt)`