# Curl with pipe : How to print the error without the progress-meter?

Tags: bash, shell, curl

Issue : Without a pipe symbol after the `curl` command, the output of the `curl` command is `curl: (21) QUOT command failed with 550`.

With a pipe symbol, `curl` detects it is not outputting to the terminal and inserts a progress-meter.

To disable the progress-meter I tried using the `s` flag, However using the `s` flag also prevents `curl: (21) QUOT command failed with 550` from being out-putted.

I want `curl` to continue outputting the `curl: (21) QUOT command failed with 550` the same way it outputs it in the terminal, but I do not want it to output the progress-meter.

The code : ( with `s` flag )

```
curl -ls -Q "DELE $remote_file" $remote_server | sed -r '/^\.{1,2}$/d'
```

Extra information : 
Perhaps this is not relavant to the question : 
The `sed` code : removes the `.` and the `..` from the output.

Update : 
The protocol that is used is `ftp`.

Comment: When you use a pipe you are piping stdout. That error though is being sent out through stderr. The terminal shows both outputs. [Check out this answer for how to pipe stderr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342826/how-to-pipe-stderr-and-not-stdout/23163017)

Comment: @JNevill, I tried `curl -l -Q "DELE $remote_file" $remote_server 2>&1 >/dev/null | sed -r '/^\.{1,2}$/d'` ,  however the progress-meter is still being printed out.

Comment: Try `curl -Ss`.  And send a bug report upstream.  The fact that curl behaves this way is a tragedy, and has been for years.  If more people complain about it, perhaps it will change.

Comment: Can you let us know which protocol is referenced by "$remote_server" ? FTP and HTTP behavior is different ?

Comment: @dash-o, an update has been added to the question, the protocol that is being used is `ftp`.

Comment: @William Pursell, your answer worked, and there does not seem to be a need for `2>&1 >/dev/null` , if you had posted your comment as an answer, I would have chosen it as the "selected answer"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The flag you are looking for is `-sS`. From `man curl`:

```
   -s, --silent
          Silent  or  quiet  mode.  Don't  show progress meter or error messages.  Makes Curl mute. It will still output the data you ask for, potentially even to the terminal/stdout
          unless you redirect it.

          Use -S, --show-error in addition to this option to disable progress meter but still show error messages.

          See also -v, --verbose and --stderr.
```