# Cron with elastic beanstalk and symfony - not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, symfony, amazon-ec2, cron, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm a newbie developer and I am messing around with Symfony and AWS. I have a Symfony app deployed via elastic beanstalk and I am trying to add a cron job every minute.

Basically I want the cron job to execute a Symfony command I created : `update-pings`, that is supposed to update some fields in my RDS DB.

I'm using a 02-crons.config file in my ./ebextensions directory that looks like this (greatly inspired from AWS documentation https://aws.amazon.com/fr/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cron-job-elastic-beanstalk/ ) :

```
files:
  "/etc/cron.d/mycron":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      * * * * * root php /var/app/current/bin/console app:update-pings


commands:
  remove_old_cron:
    command: "rm -f /etc/cron.d/mycron.bak"
```

Well, first of all, this is not working, the fields in the DB are not updating. So i connected in SSH to my EC2 instance to see what's happening.

The `mycron` file in `/etc/cron.d/`was correctly created with `* * * * * root php /var/app/current/bin/console app:update-pings`inside of it.

Now, I tried replacing the content of this file by a simple `* * * * * root echo test >> /tmp/cron_temp`, this is working perfectly, a line with 'test' is added in my `cron_temp` file every minute

I tried running the initial command `php /var/app/current/bin/console app:update-pings`manually on the instance, works perfectly as `ec2-user`

When I switch to root user using `sudo su -`, the command still works. But when I try to run it with `sudo`, it fails, not sure if that's any relevant :

```
In EnvVarProcessor.php line 171:
Environment variable not found: "DATABASE_DBNAME".
```

I believe there is something I'm missing with linux users/rights, but I'm a total newbie with that and cannot find what's going on

Any ideas ? Thanks a lot in advance ! :)

Edit 1 : I'm know logging the sterr of the commande into a file and I get the same environment variable error as when I try to run the command manually with sudo

```
In EnvVarProcessor.php line 171:
Environment variable not found: "DATABASE_DBNAME".
```

The command works fine without sudo though

Comment: That missing environment variable might be a clue. I would modify your cron command to output stderr to a file so you can see what went wrong. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342826/how-can-i-pipe-stderr-and-not-stdout)

Comment: Thx, I logged the error to a file with 2>> and I get the same Environment variable error as when I manually run the command with sudo.

```In EnvVarProcessor.php line 171:

  Environment variable not found: "DATABASE_DBNAME".```