# How do I send cron stderr to a script between pipes?

Tags: mysql, cron, database-backups

I have some MySQL databases that I back up nightly from cron, just your standard `mysqldump` command. I'd like to feed only the errors from mysqldump and/or aws to a script that will then send the error into slack. I'm struggling to figure out how to do that in the middle of the command though. I want to send stderr to slacktee, but stout to gzip and on to `aws s3 cp`. So this works fine:

`* * * * * mysqldump --host=mysql.example.com --user=mysql | gzip | aws s3 cp - s3://backs/backs/whatever.sql.gz`

That's just the usual plain ol' backup thing. But I'm trying to squeeze in stderr redirects for the mysqldump command fails, I've tried every combination of `2>&1` I could and each one doesn't do the trick. Every combination either ends with an empty gzip file or stops everything from running.

`* * * * * mysqldump --host=mysql.example.com --user=mysql dbname 2>&1 >/dev/null | /usr/local/bin/slacktee  | gzip | aws s3 cp - s3://backs/backs/whatever.sql.gz`

So if there's an error on the mysqldump command send just the error to `/usr/local/bin/slacktee` if there's no error, just send the mysqldump output to the pipe over to gzip.

I want the same thing with `aws s3 cp`, but that seems to be easier, I can just put the redirect at the end.

Edited to add: Ideally I'm hoping to avoid doing a separate script for this and keeping it all in one line in cron.

Also adding another edit. `2>&1 /dev/null` was just in this example,  I've tried making that `2>&1 /path/to/slacktee` as well as different combinations of `2>` and `1>` and some `|` in different places as well and every other different way I could think of, and that didn't work either.

Comment: `2>&1 >/dev/null`  Where do you think the output (including the errors) go to?

Comment: `/dev/null` but I've tried making that `/path/to/slacktee` and that didn't work either.

Comment: I checked `2>&1 >/dev/null`, and it seems (seeL [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2342841/724039)), that  `2>&1` makes errors go to stdout, and the `>/dev/null` does not change te earlier redirected error, (But the stdout of the command is send to `/dev/null`) in your case useless because you need the output of mysqldump.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a separate script, (mysqlbackup.sh), and change the crontab to:

```
* * * * * mysqlbackup.sh
```

Your script could look like (untested):

```
#!/bin/bash

mysqldump --host=mysql.example.com --user=mysql dbname 2>/tmp/errors | gzip > /tmp/mysqldump.gz

if [ -s /tmp/errors ];  # if file has a size
then
        echo "Something went wrong"
else
        echo "OK"
fi
```

This, of course, needs to be expanded with the `aws s3 cp...` stuff...

Comment: Thanks, I am hoping to avoid a separate script for this, if it's possible. I will keep this in mind if it turns out I can't keep this all in cron.