# How to pipe rust output

Tags: rust, pipe, zsh

### What I'm trying to do

I'm trying to apply a substitution with `sed` on an output of the rust compiler.

### Small example

Do `cargo new test`.

`src/main.rs`

```rust
fn main() {
    println("Println is a macro!!");
}
```

Now do `cargo run | sed -n -e 's/help/Help/'`.

#### Expected output

```rust
error[E0423]: expected function, found macro `println`
 --> src/main.rs:2:5
  |
2 |     println("Println is a macro!!");
  |     ^^^^^^^ not a function
  |
Help: use `!` to invoke the macro
  |
2 |     println!("Println is a macro!!");
  |            +

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0423`.
error: could not compile `rust_tmp` due to previous error
```

#### What I get

```rust
error[E0423]: expected function, found macro `println`
 --> src/main.rs:2:5
  |
2 |     println("Println is a macro!!");
  |     ^^^^^^^ not a function
  |
help: use `!` to invoke the macro
  |
2 |     println!("Println is a macro!!");
  |            +

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0423`.
error: could not compile `rust_tmp` due to previous error
```

(nothing has changed)

### What else I tried

I also tried:

- `cargo run 2>&1 sed -n -e 's/help/Help/'`

Comment: Your last try is a step in the right direction; the output you see from Rust's compiler is written on `stderr` rather than `stdout`. This isn't specific to Rust. You can see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342826/how-can-i-pipe-stderr-and-not-stdout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try piping stderr instead of stdout to sed: `cargo run 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 | sed -n -e 's/help/Help/'`.
You can also pipe both stderr & stdout to sed: `cargo run |& sed -n -e 's/help/Help/'`.

Have a look at the bash manual [chapter on redirections](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirections).