# Why GPG command doesn't allow me to grep on output or write its output into a file?

Tags: bash, io-redirection, stderr

Say I want to find "AE09" within the output of this command with the line highlighted (classically).

```
~/Downloads$ gpg --verify sha256sum.txt.gpg sha256sum.txt
    gpg: Signature made Sun 18 Dec 2022 12:54:36 GMT
    gpg:                using RSA key 27DEB15644C6B3CF3BD7D291300F846BA25BAE09
    gpg: Good signature from "Linux Mint ISO Signing Key <root@linuxmint.com>" [unknown]
    gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
    gpg:          There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.
    Primary key fingerprint: 27DE B156 44C6 B3CF 3BD7  D291 300F 846B A25B AE09
```

So I try:

```
~/Downloads$ gpg --verify sha256sum.txt.gpg sha256sum.txt | grep "AE09"
gpg: Signature made Sun 18 Dec 2022 12:54:36 GMT
gpg:                using RSA key 27DEB15644C6B3CF3BD7D291300F846BA25BAE09
gpg: Good signature from "Linux Mint ISO Signing Key <root@linuxmint.com>" [unknown]
gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
gpg:          There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.
Primary key fingerprint: 27DE B156 44C6 B3CF 3BD7  D291 300F 846B A25B AE09
```

Giving me entire output instead of "Primary key" line.

Then I try(to grep later):

```
~/Downloads$ gpg --verify sha256sum.txt.gpg sha256sum.txt > res
```

Leaving me empty file res.

Then I try to use the tool output:

```
~/Downloads$ gpg --output res --verify sha256sum.txt.gpg sha256sum.txt
gpg: Signature made Sun 18 Dec 2022 12:54:36 GMT
gpg:                using RSA key 27DEB15644C6B3CF3BD7D291300F846BA25BAE09
gpg: Good signature from "Linux Mint ISO Signing Key <root@linuxmint.com>" [unknown]
gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
gpg:          There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.
Primary key fingerprint: 27DE B156 44C6 B3CF 3BD7  D291 300F 846B A25B AE09
```

Then I come here as ideas are exhausted. My thoughts are that the command doesn't simply have stdout and just prints the data internally?

Thanks,

Comment: `gpg` is writing this shown text on `stderr`. Try: `gpg --verify sha256sum.txt.gpg sha256sum.txt 2>&1 | grep -F "AE09"`

Comment: Or by adding ampersand after pipe symbol: `gpg --verify sha256sum.txt.gpg sha256sum.txt |& grep "AE09"`

Comment: Do this answer to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342826/how-can-i-pipe-stderr-and-not-stdout?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C302.7558